# Raise integer x to power x, without exponentiation built-ins

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

**Task -** The title pretty much sums it up: raise an integer *x* to power *x*, where `0<x`.

**Restrictions:**

- Use of exponentiation, `exp()`, `ln()`, and any other powers-related language built-ins, like `pow()`, `x^x`, `x**x` is forbidden.
- You can assume that the given integer fits the limits of the programming language of your choice.

**Test cases:**

```
Input | Output
---------------
2     | 4
3     | 27
5     | 3125
6     | 46656
10    | 10000000000
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: Can we accept input as a string?

Comment: I have made an edit to this, hoping it will be reopened. I deleted rule 3 and instead stated that it should be a full program, as the OP probably intended

Comment: Much better, @Mr.Xcoder but I suggest removing (or rewording) the second restriction. Does "not a function" exclude JS from participating? I'd also suggest, for the purposes of the challenge, that we should have to handle `0` and that the expected output be specified (`0` or `1` or either). Finally, having to handle negative integers would be a nice addition to the challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy added js back in... calculated 0^0 on the apple calculator and it returned 1. Maybe 1 should be the chosen value, because Python also returns `1` for `0^0`. However, `Foundation`+ Swift returns 0

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, outputting `0` might present more of a challenge in some languages (it'd add 3 bytes to my answer!) but either option works for me.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure how to interpret "*The program must not handle `0`*". Should that be "*need not handle*" instead? 2. At present the majority of the answers to this question don't follow the rule that the answer must be a full program. I'm not sure why @Mr.Xcoder added that requirement, but I don't think the question should be reopened until the question is consistent with the existing answers (either because the requirement is removed or because the offending answers have been deleted).

Comment: @PeterTaylor that's what the OP initially stated, ambiguously though, I will remove that rule. For (1) I will reword that

Comment: @PeterTaylor Done, now it's consistent with the answers.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, I've removed the "restriction" that we need not handle `0` and instead specified that `0<x` in the lead-in. I also removed the restriction that code shouldn't throw errors; that should go without saying. Feel free to roll back if necessary.

Comment: @Shaggy it's a good edit, now covers everything well

Comment: @Shaggy and what was wrong with my good luck wish?))))

Comment: @Mr. Xcoder for C, i suppose this will be an function int f(x), which will compile in gcc and ms visual studio. so we can put that code in some code.h file. then make our test program like follows: `#include <stdio.h>
#include "code.h"
int main()
{
 int i;
 for(i=1; i<11;i++)
  printf("%u %u\n", i, f(i));
 return 0;
} ` bytesize of code.h is measured

Comment: Next time: Evaluate the xth hyperoperation of x

Comment: @xakepp35 people (for some reason) on this site dislike wishing people luck. And it was Peter Taylor, not Shaggy who deleted it.

Comment: The challenge allows \$x=0\$ to have undefined behavior, and that's fine... but I wish answers that took advantage of this (most of which return \$0\$ in that case) would also show an alternative answer that returns \$1\$, as it's generally accepted that \$0^0=1\$. I also wish answers in languages that have a shorter built-in would mention what that built-in is. This is how I feel in general regarding challenges with clauses of this kind (especially when the question asked is quite fundamental), of which there are many on CGCC.

Comment: @MatthewRoh : sure …. then we won't many test cases to work with at all - `9^9^9` is already `1.22 billion` bits, larger than what `gnu GMP` is willing to return, while `10^10^10` is a lovely `33.2193 billion` bits. Luckily for us, `8^8^8` is ***only*** ~ `2^2^25.58`

Answer (score 18):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda n:eval('1'+'*n'*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5ValpijoW6orq2ulQdEmv/T8osUMhUy8xSKEvPSUzUMDTStuDgLijLzShQyddI0MjX/AwA)

Answer (score 17):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

For *x<sup>x</sup>*, takes *x* as left argument and *x* as right argument.

```apl
×/⍴⍨
```

[Try all cases online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/wPyy1OLgKzD0/Uf9W551LviP0RIwYgLQhtDaVMobQalDQ0A)

`×/` product of

`⍴⍨` arg copies arg

And here here is one that handles negative integers too:

```apl
×/|⍴|÷1⌊|×⊢
```

[Try all cases!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXEBWQACQZfQ/IL88tQjIOjxdv@ZR75aaw9sNH/V01Rye/qhr0X@I7KEVBnWPelccWm9ooP2od7ORIQA)

`×/` the product of

`|` absolute value

`⍴` **r**epetitions of

`|` the absolute value

`÷` divided by

`1⌊` the **L**esser of 1 and

`|` the absolute value

`×` times

`⊢` the argument

The built-in Power primitive is:

```apl
x*y
```

Comment: In the one for negative numbers you used power

Comment: @Joao-3 Thanks. Fixed both that and the wrong result. Was just an extra thing, anyway.

Comment: When you forget that multiplication is not asterisk...

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematica, 16 bytes

I've got two solutions at this byte count:

```
1##&@@#~Table~#&
```

Here, `#~Table~#` creates a list of `n` copies of `n`. Then the `List` head is replaced by `1##&` which multiplies all its arguments together.

```
Nest[n#&,1,n=#]&
```

This simply stores the input in `n` and then multiplies `1` by `n`, `n` times.

Comment: `#~Product~{#}&`

Comment: @alephalpha ah, good point. You can post that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> <s>28</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```js
n=>g=(x=n)=>--x?n*g(x):n
```

---

### Try It

```js
f=
n=>g=(x=n)=>--x?n*g(x):n
o.innerText=f(i.value=3)()
i.oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)()
```

```html
<input id=i min=1 type=number><pre id=o>
```

---

### History

#### 25 bytes

```js
f=(n,x=n)=>--x?n*f(n,x):n
```

#### 28 bytes

```js
n=>eval(1+("*"+n).repeat(n))
```

#### 33 bytes

```js
n=>eval(Array(n).fill(n).join`*`)
```

Answer (score 6):

## R, 22 bytes

reads `x` from stdin.

```
prod(rep(x<-scan(),x))
```

generates a list of `x` copies of `x`, then computes the product of the elements of that list. When `x=0`, the `rep` returns `numeric(0)`, which is a numeric vector of length `0`, but the `prod` of that is 1, so `0^0=1` by this method, which is consistent with R's builtin exponentiation, so that's pretty neat.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@19QlJ@iUZRaoFFho1ucnJinoalToan53/Q/AA)

Comment: Dang, I find a challenge where I am positive I've come up with an excellent solution exactly like this and you've beat me. And beat me by 3 years! I've barely been on Code Golf for a year now!

Answer (score 6):

## Regex  (ECMAScript+`(?^*)`<sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)</sup>), 13 bytes

```
^(x(?^*x+))*$
```

Takes its input in unary, as a string of `x` characters whose length represents the number. Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method. It can yield outputs bigger than the input, and is really good at multiplying.)

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Raise-integer-x-to-power-x-with-lookinto)

This version uses molecular lookinto, a new feature in [RegexMathEngine](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine). The basic form `(?^*`...`)` matches the expression inside it against the entire input string. (With a parameter, it evaluates it against the contents of a backreference, e.g. `(?^5*`...`)` to look into `\5`.)

On every iteration of the outer loop, there are \$n\$ possible matching states of the inner loop, and at the end of \$n\$ iterations, the match is complete. In a complete match, each iteration can independently be at any one of \$n\$ states, so there are \$n^n\$ total possible matches.

Changing the `*` at the end to `+` would make it give a result of \$0\$ for \$n=0\$.

```
^           # tail = N = input number
(
    x       # tail -= 1
    (?^*    # Non-atomic lookinto - starts with tail = N
        x+  # Create a choice between N possibilities
    )
)*$         # Loop as many times as possible, minimum 0. This will loop N times,
            # because it subtracts 1 from tail on each iteration. The minimum of
            # 0 iterations gives a correct result of 1 for N==0.
```

The constant-power \$n^k\$ version of this can be seen in [Quartic Summation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156100/quartic-summation/250206#250206), for which there is also a method that doesn't require non-atomic lookaround. It might be impossible to implement \$n^n\$ without non-atomic lookaround, due to it being impossible to create \$m\$ number of choices (with the value \$m\$ being accessed via a backreference) without the guarantee of having \$O(m)\$ avaiable space.

The constant-base \$k^n\$ version of this would be e.g. `^((.+)*)+` or `^(x(||))*$` for \$3^n\$.

## Regex  (PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub>), 26 bytes

```
^(x((?<*(?*^x+|(?2)).)))*$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbNbttGED4W0FOMmdbapShXctDUEEULrizABhI7UGQ0jaIQNLmUiFBLglzGP62vfYBeeylQ9JgX6Ju0x75GL539kURbAkpY1P7MfPP3zci_fg7ztCrlx5-H4eep1U7zsGCH7SNr9tf4WcTihDN4PRyPDv3h5enIv7o4n_jfn59OzuCo8SzhYVpFDPpK6WBx3AgXQQF-Pp2BB2Pru5ubj9fPqx_u7t5OFi9uFuSPSsTtoz8_kFtCBn2bDOwPt62fyOCQ0gNKqf2lFvj7i3_pU13LATv3_LzVdWuGS1EkfC4tb86SDE9ZsDzekjtuJFxAjkvhs6LIChJmvBSgvLaXrCyDOaPwYymiXi9ECej3wRzLpTpnPEpdKJioCg5d92ELU-7DLGIOXGdZCpkXB2kpYZUZAzc9_ObFzG0APkkMRCXQnzOD4RsponGIrsDV8OxkfGRTc-lAmdyzLCZrx79endTkMa3KinxIBgMdRJhVAnqwDpTK8CylBsqDHlhPglfKloVa1ntu0XU-YmTPQkeyTkrjoVHxMplzFkGa8bl-Bby8YYWrEra888MgTdENE7vZ-ddpFn4EO3TgU5ZEYEeBCDB3MklyCZ4HRN7YdH-DQQ12q7WuTMdUZhkknCCAcjCfIhFSxklO292Z13F1CJodkIeeRQY9y8VVy8v1l0XJYIifPYrnFSI-P_QFFhV1JfwcFwq6DpTwvBJSXQWGJQS7YKv9MhDhwlex2Ju1RitYWaXC0SVwTeO9OX83UidxXDK8xHgxhLlYPBKws08sFKhlKoENuLK_zJOUEUOKN68nY5qHB6GPzhLqGIx3o_GlPxmNX51fnExGp6vj0dvJ6OJU7veVT-bbeNKhGwbvFUhAk_t6N6i3kauF7m1lw8d9IJgfF9nSzwMhWMFJgSy_uHr50gDUdbB1BbsVmMTVytt1b2DJFgpGsKbgCsKp8dLZxbOnANpUmiyTOki7S92aUMRy8b9CBQurokwyvlNQmY2zAtR0uV8zFydGiiOa6EZOuKO5R90V41V5UIV3MD2ByBKiBFblx_rzrgN5VuK1vsGRH5Fmu2mMyod3ZW5RZs-r87zX4_JwsAMXWkq-BV2KA4N3Nlh61kpznN3o3ZR3W92Zi8NmiZkgpQPN26Z0DBNU4uXMq-mvk5B4XPZg3-NdF1qtpB7xipT3FNApaYQ033MMCVOH0oqfMbG-iuCfn38B_GlJ8EqPEHSsZk33kmzKx-xSxKx3FDqdYEOovw2ncW3KSN0t5zRuvwP7-8bGnme6bjy-HPsXl69OJsMz-khR0a_WXquJIYqKPbHB8FdnS3cz_XF-m4h3THL5PDQ2712NFReMkU182w2tBdZ7Wp-I-hJnxnpg60jwp0P_D_Db7532t3r5Hw)

This solution uses non-atomic recursion, lookahead, and lookbehind to emulate non-atomic variable-length lookbehind. The algorithm used is the same as that of the 13 byte version.

```
^                           # tail = N = input number
(
    x                       # tail -= 1
    (                       # Define subroutine (?2)
        (?<*                # Non-atomic lookbehind
            (?*             # Non-atomic lookahead
                ^           # If we've reached tail==0, then:
                x+          # create a choice between N possibilities.
            |
                (?2)        # Otherwise, recursively call (?2).
            )
            .               # tail += 1 (Go back 1 character at a time)
        )
    )
)*$                         # Loop as many times as possible, minimum 0. This
                            # will loop N times, because it subtracts 1 from
                            # tail on each iteration. The minimum of 0 iterations
                            # gives a correct result of 1 for N==0.
```

The equivalent in a hypothetical engine with real (not emulated) non-atomic variable-length lookbehind would be `^(x(?<*^x+.*))*$` (**16 bytes**).

### Regex  (PCRE2 v10.35+ without lookbehind), 59 bytes

```
^(?=(x*)\1(x?))(((?*x+(?!\1)()?|\2+$))x(?(?=\2\1)(?4)))*\1$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbNbttGED4W0FOsmdTeJalUVNrUEE0Lji3ABhI7UGQ0jaUSNLmUFqGWBLmMZSe-9gF67aVA0WMeKD32NXrp7I8k2hJQwpL2Z-abv2-G_v1LXGR1JT_hNI6_XFntrIhL2m3vW5OvwycJTRmn6M3xcNANjy9OBuHl-dko_OnsZHSK9ltPGI-zOqHoQCk9mx224llUorC4mqAADa2XNzcfrp_XP9_evhvNXtzM8F-1SNv7X_1fcD_AC5uMPbzoE4Ix7tsLB_d3xh7BpP953HWeErLAfZAbd-Vh_3tCiD32nmqIv7_5lzxGt1xkF0FYOJ7fcK0SJeNT6dv6jOVwSqP54YbcYYtxgQpYipCWZV7iOOeVQCoue06rKppSgj5VIun1YpBABwfIHMulOqc8yXxUUlGXHHn-_Qam3Md5Ql10necZyoM0yioJq8wYuKvuDy8mfgvBw1KEVYrDKTUYoZHCGgfrGl0enx4N921iLl1UsTuap3jl-HfLk4Y8JFZZkQ_OUV8HEee1QD20CpTI8CylhpQHPWQ9Cl4pWxZoWWNukVU-UuDXTEeySkrrvlXzik05TVCW86n-inh1Q0tfJWx-G8ZRloEbJnazC6-zPP6A7NhFH3OWIDuJRAS5k0mSSxQECMsbm-yuMYjBdpxVZTqmMvOIcQwAysHiCoiQUY4L0vYmQcfXIWh2oCIOLNzvWT6snKDQPxaw8xg-OwTOa0B83g0FFBV0JfwUFgq6CcR4UQuprgKDEiK7pMv9PBLxLFSx2Ou1RitpVWfC1SXwTWu-PXs_UCdpWlG4hHghhKmYPRCw8480FqBlKgEturQ_L1hGsSHF2zejISniZ3EIzmLiGoz3g-FFOBoMX5-dH40GJ8vjwbvR4PxE7neVT-bXeNIhawbvlEBAk_tmN6hvI9cIPdjIRgj7SNAwLfN5WERC0JLjElh-fvnqlQFo6kDrCroQkMTlKth2b2DxBgpEsKLgEsJt8NLdxrPHANpUxuasCdL2iN8QSmgh_leopHFdViznWwWV2TQvkZoudyvmwsTIYIhj3ciMu5p7xF8yXpUHVHgH0hOJnGElsCw_1J97LiryCq71DbwUErzX3jNG5cM9mVuQ2QmaPO_1uDzsb8FFjpJ3kEdgYPDOGkvPWmmO0xu9u-Ke4018GDZzyASuXLS32JOOQYIquJwEDf1VEljAZQ8eBNzzkeOwZsRLUt4RBE5JI3hvzCEkSB1IK36m2Po2Qf_8-huCVwuDKz1CwLGGNd1LsikfsksRs9lR4DSDhlB_a07D2pSR-BvOadyDDtrdNTZ2AtN1w-HFMDy_eH00Oj4lDxQV_RrttZwYoqzpIxsU3jobuuvpD_PbRLxlksvnvrX-3tZYaUkpXse32dBaYLUnzYmoL2FmrAa2jgReHfp_gD_-7LR_1Mv_AA)

This demonstrates this to be possible without the use of lookbehind or recursion. It works by emulating operation on \$n\$ within the space of \$n/2\$, using one of those halves as a counter for the outer loop, and the other half for the inner loop.

<sup>(I wrote this version on July 29, and am finally posting it now.)</sup>

```
^                         # Anchor to start; tail = N = input number
(?=(x*)\1(x?))            # \1 = floor(N / 2); \2 = N % 2
(
    (                     # Define subroutine (?4):
        (?*
            x+(?!\1)      # Add \1 to possibility count
            ()?           # Double the possibility count of the above
        |
            \2+$          # If \2==1, add 1 to possibility count
        )
    )
    x                     # tail -= 1
    (?(?=\2\1)            # If tail ≥ \2 + \1:
        (?4)              # Call subroutine (?4), to multiply its possibility
                          # count with the above
    )
)*                        # For every possible iteration count, from 0 to the
                          # maximum, add the above to the possibility count
\1$                       # Assert tail == \1
```

### Regex  (ECMAScript+`(?*)`<sup>[RME](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine)</sup> <sub><sup>/ PCRE2 v10.35+</sup></sub>), 81 bytes

```
^(?=(x*)\1(x?))((?*x+(?!\1)(|)|\2+$)x((?=\2\1)(?*x+(?!\1)(|)|\2+$)|(?!\2\1)))*\1$
```

[Try it on replit.com](https://replit.com/@Davidebyzero/regex-Raise-integer-x-to-power-x) - RegexMathEngine
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbLbttGFF0W0FeMmdSeIalUVNDUEE0Lri3ABhI7VWQ0jaUSNDmUBqGGBDmMZdfe9gO67aZA0WU-KF32N7rpnYck2hJQwpJm7uPc96V__xwXWV3JTziN489XVjsr4pJ22_vW5MvwWUJTxil6ezwcdMPji5NBeHl-Ngp_PDsZnaL91jPG46xOKDpQSi9mh614FpUoLK4mKEBD6_ubm4_XL-ufbm_fj2avbmb4r1qk7f0vP_yM-wFe2GTs4UWfEIz79sLB_Z2xR_A9uR93nedkAdRg3JWkLdx7eZdMQuyx91wD__3Vv-SpTctFdhGEheP5DYcrUTI-lR6vaSwHKo3mhxtyhy3GBSrgKEJalnmJ45xXAqlo7TmtqmhKCfqlEkmvF4MEOjhAhiyPik55kvmopKIuOfL8hw1MeY_zhLroOs8zlAdplFUSVpkxcFfdb19N_BaCh6UIq8SHU2owQiOFNQ7Wlbs8Pj0a7tvEMF1UsTuap3jl-DdLSkMeEqusyAfnqK-DiPNaoB5aBUpkeJZSQ8qDHrKeBK-ULQu0rDG3yCofKXTdTEeySkrroVXzik05TVCW86n-inh1Q0tfJWx-G8ZRloEbJnZzC6-zPP6I7NhFn3KWIDuJRAS5k0mSRxQECEuOTXbXGMRgO86qMh1TmXnEOAYA5WBxBY2QUY4L0vYmQcfXIejuQEUcWLjfs3w4OUGhfyxo22P47BCg14D4shsKKCroSvgpHBR0E4jxohZSXQUGJUR2SZf3eSTiWahisddnjVbSqs6Eq0vgm4F9d_ZhoChpWlFgQrwQwlTMHgnY-ScaC9AylYDBXdqfFyyj2DTFu7ejISniF3EIzmLiGowPg-FFOBoM35ydH40GJ0vy4P1ocH4i77vKJ_NrPOmQdQfvlNCAJvfNaVDfRq4RerCRjRDukaBhWubzsIiEoCXHJXT5-eXr1wagqQOjK-hCQBKXp2Ab38DiDRSIYNWCSwi30Zfutj57CqBNZWzOmiBtj_gNoYQW4n-FShrXZcVyvlVQmU3zEqntcrfqXNgYGax2rAeZcVf3HvGXHa_KAyq8A-mJRM6wEliWH-rPPRcVeQVszYFXRYL32nvGqHy4J3MLMjtBs897PS6J_S24yFHyDvIILAzeWWPpXSvNcXqjb1fcc7yJD8tmDpnAlYv2FnvSMUhQBcxJ0NBfJYEFXM7gQcA9HzkOa0a8bMo7gsApaQTvjTmEBKkDadWfKba-TtA_v_6G4NXCgKVXCDjWsKZnSQ7l4-5SjdmcKHCawUCov3VPw9mUkfgbzmncgw7a3TU2dgIzdcPhxTA8v3hzNDo-JY8UVfs1xmu5MURZ0yc2KLx1NnTX2x_2t4l4yyaXz0Nr_b1tsNKSUryOb3OgtcDqTpobUTNhZ6wWto4EXh36f4A__uy0v9PH_wA) - PCRE2 v10.40+

This is a port of the 59 byte version. Basic ECMAScript lacks not only lookbehind, but subroutine calls and conditionals as well. The only feature added to basic ECMAScript is `(?*`...`)`, molecular lookahead (a.k.a. non-atomic lookahead). Note that `(|)` must be used instead of `()?` due to ECMAScript's [no-empty-optional](https://github.com/Davidebyzero/RegexMathEngine/issues/1) rule.

<sup>(I wrote this version on July 29, and am finally posting it now.)</sup>

```
^                         # Anchor to start; tail = N = input number
(?=(x*)\1(x?))            # \1 = floor(N / 2); \2 = N % 2
(
    (?*                   # Define "subroutine":
        x+(?!\1)          # Add \1 to possibility count
        (|)               # Double the possibility count of the above
    |
        \2+$              # If \2==1, add 1 to possibility count
    )
    x                     # tail -= 1
    # Multiply the above possibility count with the following:
    (                     # Emulated conditional, upon whether tail ≥ \2 + \1
        (?=\2\1)          # If yes:
        # Call "subroutine" (duplicates it, since this regex flavor lacks
        # subroutine calls) to multiply with the above possibility count
        (?*
            x+(?!\1)
            (|)
        |
            \2+$
        )
    |
        (?!\2\1)          # If no: Use possibility multiplier of 1
    )
)*                        # For every possible iteration count, from 0 to the
                          # maximum, add the above to the possibility count
\1$                       # Assert tail == \1
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pure bash, 43

```bash
echo $[$1<2?1:$[$1<2?2:$1]#`printf 1%0$1d`]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S8svUihJLS5JTixOVcjMU6g21NMzNK21VkjJ51IAgoKizLySNAUl1RQFXTsFJQUVmGKwbHFqiYKuLkLwf2pyRr6CSrSKoY2RvaEVlGFkpWIYq5wANcpQ1UDFMCUh9n9Kfl7qfwA).

Not sure if this is bending the rules too much - I'm not using any of the listed banned builtins, but I am using base conversion.

- `printf 1%0$1d` outputs a `1` followed by n `0`s
- `$[b#a]` is an arithmetic expansion to treat `a` as a base `b` number, which gives the required result.  Unfortunately base <2 does not work, so the extra `?:` bits handle input n=1.

Maximum input is 15, because bash uses signed 64-bit integers (up to 2<sup>31</sup>-1).

Comment: Same problem as I had, this doesn't work for x=1. Nonetheless, very interesting approach.

Comment: @MaxLawnboy Thanks for pointing that out - that sadly bloated my answer.  Perhaps I can figure out another shorter version...

Comment: Cool stuff. Always wished to learn bash, but always been too lazy for it =)

Answer (score 5):

## [Standard ML](http://sml-family.org/), 42 bytes

```
fn x=>foldl op*1(List.tabulate(x,fn y=>x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sml-mlton#K0vMUSjIL08tUrD9n5anUGFrl5afk5KjkF@gZajhk1lcoleSmFSak1iSqlGhA1RQaWtXoan531qhoCgzr0RBwzMPqCI/uATIS1fQgJhkpqlp/R8A)

Explanation:

```
fn y => x                 (* An anonymous function that always returns the inputted value *)
List.tabulate(x, fn y=>x) (* Create a list of size x where each item is x *)
foldl op* 1               (* Compute the product of the entire list *)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: TIO has MLton now. https://tio.run/nexus/sml-mlton#@1@WmKNQkF@eWqRgq5CWp1Bha5eWn5OSo5BfoGWo4ZNZXKJXkphUmpNYkqpRoQNUUGlrV6Gpac1VUJSZV6Kg4ZkHVJAfXALkpStoQAwyA8r//w8A

Comment: Oh that's awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 13 bytes

```
/o
\i@/.&.t&*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@fzxWT6aCvp6ZXoqb1/78ZAA)

#### Explanation

```
/o
\i@/...
```

This is a framework for programs that read and write decimal integers and operate entirely in Cardinal mode (so programs for most arithmetic problems).

```
.    Duplicate n.
&.   Make n copies of n.
t    Decrement the top copy to n-1.
&*   Multiply the top two values on the stack n-1 times, computing n^n.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <sup><s>3</s></sup> 2.5 bytes (<sup><s>6</s></sup> 5 nibbles)

```
`*^$_
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://staging.ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWSxO04lTiIWyo0IKFxhAGAA)

Returns the correct answer of \$1\$ for an input of \$0\$, as it is generally accepted that \$0^0=1\$ (even though this challenge doesn't require it, and several of the other answers take advantage of this and return \$0\$, or loop infinitely, for an input of \$0\$).

The ASCII representation uses `^`, but in this context it's a Replicate operator, not exponentiation.

Explanation, shown with example input of 7:

```
`*^$_
    _     # Input coerced to a list: [7]
   $      # Input: 7
  ^       # Replicate: [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
`*        # Product (returns 1 for an empty list): 823543
```

The builtin is just **0.5 bytes (1 nibble)**:

```
^
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWC-MgNJS7YKE5hAEA)

Comment: Input-coerced-to-a-list is clever.  Well done.  And it's great to have more nibbles competition...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks! It was your answer that inspired me to try. (And I didn't realize `_` could do that until I started using `p`. The documentation was a bit unclear on that.)

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 4 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
/×▽.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=f%20%E2%86%90%20%2F%C3%97%E2%96%BD.%0A%0Af%203%0Af%204%0Af%205%0Af%206)

```
  ▽.  # list of N Ns
/×    # product
```

Note: can also do /×↯.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ẋ⁸P
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wV/ejxh0B////NwUA)**

#### How?

```
ẋ⁸P - Main link: x             e.g. 4
 ⁸  - link's left argument, x       4
ẋ   - repeat left right times       [4,4,4,4]
  P - product                       256
```

Comment: Darn, I wanted to do this. :P

Comment: @Jonathan Allan is it 3 bytes, or 3 wide-characters? let us view source code hex dump, please, to make correct decision on actual code bytesize. ;-) and make the corrections

Comment: @xakepp35 Jelly uses a SBCS and the *bytes* link in the header points to it. The program with hexdump `F7 88 50` works as intended.

Comment: @Dennis thanks for reply! i could not ever imagine such a language before =)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

-2 bytes because the spec changed and I no longer need an exponent argument.

```ruby
->x{eval [x]*x*?*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7ON@a9rV1GdWpaYoxBdEatVoWWvVfu/oLSkWCEtOj21pFivJD8@M/a/CQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
.DP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/nEvD/vxkA) or [Try all examples](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#K6us/K/nEvBf53@0kY6xjqmOmY6hQSwA)

```
.D  # pop a,b    push b copies of a 
    # 05AB1E implicitly takes from input if there aren't enough values on the stack
    # For input 5, this gives us the array: [5,5,5,5,5]
  P # Take the product of that array
    # Implicit print
```

Comment: Looks like you enjoyed `.D`. First time I've seen it used.

Comment: ah, i dont get what is happening here.. seems to be too exotic and no explanation on how that works.  =(

Comment: @xakepp35 Does that help?

Comment: `.D` can be `и` for -1 (probably a builtin that wasn't available before?)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 19 bytes

```
..@OI:1*s;pu!vqW|($
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@6@n5@DvaWWoVWxdUKpYVhheo6Hy/7@hAQA)

[Step by Step](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIC4gLgogICAgQCBPCkkgOiAxICogcyA7IHAgdQohIHYgcSBXIHwgKCAkIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=Mwo=&speed=20)

Expands out onto a cube with side length 2

```
    . .
    @ O
I : 1 * s ; p u
! v q W | ( $ .
    . .
    . .
```

- `I:1` Takes the input, duplicates it and pushs 1.  This sets up the stack with a counter, multiplier and result.
- `*s;` Multiples the TOS, swaps the result with previous and remove previous.
- `pu` Bring the counter item to the TOS.  U-turn.  This use to be a lane change, but needed to shave a byte.
- `|($` This was done to save a byte.  When hit it skips the decrement. reflects, decrements the counter and skips the no op wrapping around the cube.
- `!vqW` Test the counter.  If truthy skip the redirect, put the counter on BOS, change lane back onto the multiplier.  Otherwise redirect.
- `|sO@` this is the end sequence redirected to from counter test.  Goes past the horizontal reflect, swaps the TOS bringing result to the TOS, ouput and halt.

Answer (score 3):

## x86_64 machine language for Linux, <s>14 11</s> 10 bytes

```
0:   6a 01                   pushq  $0x1
2:   58                      pop    %rax
3:   89 f9                   mov    %edi,%ecx
5:   f7 ef                   imul   %edi
7:   e2 fc                   loop   5
9:   c3                      retq
```

To [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYrNDoIwEITvfYpJE5JdwQP@YpAncT2Q1UoPFoMcmhievZbDl28yM7p9qaakY/jO0KGfMNzunZV46qWWeGwkNheJbuUs8ekyu5xVou5ta4wPM969D8Q/A7hxIqyVR4e6zbrikFWWYKwH4DPl3RFs8UDxkGAr@ApEuaUNE/PA5Bnc5vdiFpPSHw), compile and run the following C program.

```
const char h[]="\x6a\1\x58\x89\xf9\xf7\xef\xe2\xfc\xc3";

int main(){
  for( int i = 1; i < 4; i++ ) {
    printf( "%d %d\n", i, ((int(*)())h)(i) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
ẋΠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuovOoCIsIiIsIjYiXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
f(x)=∏_{n=1}^xx
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qqjpk4olhz)

The `^` is not used for exponentation in this case.
-2 bytes thanks to [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow).

Comment: The brackets around the `x` can be removed and it will still parse fine, so `f(x)=∏_{n=1}^xx`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```hs
f y=product$y<$[1..y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#y03MzFOwVcjMK0ktSkwuUVBRKM7IL1fQU8hNLFBIA9JFqYkp/9MUKm0LivJTSpNLVCptVKIN9fQqY///jzbUMdIx1jHRMdUx0zE0iAUA)

- Saved 1 byte, thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)
- Saved 2 bytes, thanks to [nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34531/nimi)

Comment: `f y=foldr1(*)$y<$[1..y]` is a byte shorter.

Comment: `product$y<$[1..y]`

Comment: Not sure how I managed to forget about product, thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 10 bytes

```
{!1[n*]n*}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#@1@taBidpxWbp1X7X4lLw0jBWMFUwUzB0ECTK0ZBUSG/tOQ/AA)

Two-argument exponentiation for the same size:

```
{%1[x*]y*}
```

Both are functions. Repeats a function that multiplies `1` by `n` `n` times.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>32</s> 26 bytes

```scala
n=>List.fill(n)(n).product
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/scala#HYxBCsIwEEWvMstkM@hWacGlUFceQGI60ZE4E5KpCOLZa@3y8977en1QNDgFFqC3kYwNDqXAB14hQ9rBUQy6HgaVG3QwS9cP3AwT5@zEO0HTP/NYqo5TtHm/ls4vNiuedaqRsNnIgjeygYUaPkNxl6Vczv06kseklUK8u1JZLIuH77zd/AA) (Added conversion to long in the TIO so it wouldn't overflow on n=10.)

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code (Linux), 18 bytes

```
31 c0 ff c0 31 db 39 df 74 07 0f af c7 ff c3 eb f5 c3
```

It expects a C declaration as follows `extern int XpowX(int)`.

#### Disassembled

```
XpowX:
  # edi : input register
  # ebx : counter
  # eax : result register
  xor  %eax, %eax    # result  = 0
  inc  %eax          # result += 1
  xor  %ebx, %ebx    # counter = 0
  loop:
    cmp  %ebx, %edi  # if (counter == input)
    je   done        #   return result
    imul %edi, %eax  # result  *= input
    inc        %ebx  # counter += 1
    jmp   loop
  done:
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
ÆUÃ×
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=xlXD1w==&input=Ng==)

### Explanation

```
ÆUÃ×       // implicit: U = input integer
Uo{U} r*1  // ungolfed

Uo{ }      // create array [0, U) and map each value to...
   U       //   the input value
      r*1  // reduce with multiplication, starting at 1          
           // implicit output of result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Flurry](https://github.com/Reconcyl/flurry), 16 bytes

```
<>{{}}<<>()>{}{}
```

#### Run example

```
$ ./flurry -nin -c "<>{{}}<<>()>{}{}" 4
256
$ ./flurry -nin -c "<>{{}}<<>()>{}{}" 5
3125
```

Multiply `n` `n` times to 1. The lambda expression is `n (\x. \y. n (x y)) I` where `\y. n (x y)` or `n ∘ x` is the product of Church numeral of `n` and `x`, and its SKIB-transformation is as follows:

```
n (\x. \y. n (x y)) I
S I (\n. \x. \y. n (x y)) n I
S I (\n. \x. S (K n) x) n I
S I (\n. S (K n)) n I
S I (S ∘ K) n I
```

So the direct translation of this expression into Flurry gives the code above.

Expanding the `S` in front gives `n ((S ∘ K) n) I`, which does not change bytes:

```
({})[<<>()>{}]{}
```

If direct exponentiation is allowed, it is **6 bytes**: `({}){}` (pop n, push n, pop n; evaluates to `n n`), because `n m` evaluates to `m^n` when `n` and `m` are Church numerals.

Answer (score 2):

## [1+](https://esolangs.org/wiki/1%2B), <s>29</s> <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
1."1##/"\*\1+\"/^"/<1+#:
```

This was already shockingly short, given how messy it is to create a halting loop... I did a poor job on stack manipulation, so it can probably be improved.

### Special notes on 25 -> 24

> **Remember that you're programming in brainfuck.** It's tempting to avoid confusion and tedium by thinking in terms of higher-level abstractions as much as possible, rather than thinking in brainfuck. This can buy enough control to make a working program, usually at the cost of such inefficiencies as:
> -excessive pointer movement, sometimes as simple as ">+<->" and sometimes less apparent; often a result of doing things in an intuitively appealing order. -- Daniel B. Cristofani

This applies to 1+ as well. I designed this program with pseudo-code, which results in two consecutive `/`s - cuz there are only three elements on the stack, replacing it with `\` saves one byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [8 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
xõPÑ_=>$
```

## Explained

Unpacked: `*v{_}\1=>`

```
    \        Fold...
*            ...with multiplication after...
v{           ...mapping with key of v...
  _          ...by replacing with input
}            End map
      1      Literal one
        =>   inclusive range to...
          _  ...input, implied
```

Comment: Wow, nice language! I like how the source code is compressed from a readable notation.

Comment: Thanks! Glad you like it :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```
|x|(|mut y|{for _ in 1..x{y*=x}y})(x)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Xc3BDoIwDIDh@56icuqMEgaBGFSOvIbxwCKJDDNGHNn27HO7LIZbmy/9K9dFeS5geo4CKRgCoIZFobfaop1WBZs1fJbwgFEAy3NttuNdu81R1NQD0CtxhIRCPLv1HfIWekq@r0EOIdaHTeDKyguFcwdxIPHJR45CvcUBs7IF47ITcCxpiP1TlajaU52o3lOTqNkTK5KxIqLzPw)

This might be able to be shortened once [bindings_after_at](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65490) stabilizes by using `|mut y@x|` instead.

Comment: 26 bytes: `|x|(1..x).fold(1,|a,_|a*x)`

Comment: @madlaina Feel free to post that as your own solution! It works differently than mine does and is certainly a lot shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 17 bytes

```perl
$_=eval"$_*"x$_.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3ja1LDFHSSVeS6lCJV7P8P9/Iy5jLlMuMy5Dg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULcgA)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2** ::

and finally, the super overskill version that uses binary squaring algorithm, safely catches division by zero, and  properly handles negative integer bases and negative integer exponents — *that's quite a nifty bit of data sanity checking and edge case handling for 3 lines of code that has no hard-coded constants at all, plus avoiding use of the exponentiation operator (`^` or `**`)*

Center column is function output, and right most column is reference output.

It could even handle some extremely large magnitude negative exponents, like `x^x` for :

```
-16777213  ^  ()  -5.53904374025776e-121210664
                  -5.53904374025776e-121210664
```

> `-log(!_)` *exists within the function merely to return* `+inf`

```
for __ in -3 -2 -1 0 '' -0 1 2 3; do 

    jot 13 -4 | 

    gawk -v PREC=2000 -Mbe '

    func ____(___,__,_){return(__+=(_="")<__?_:___)<++_\
        ?(!__?_:___?_/____(___,-__):-log(!_)):__<++_?___\
        :(__%_?___:!!_)*____(___*___,int(__/_))

    } BEGIN { CONVFMT = "%.15g"
           _ = ""
    } ($++NF = " ^ (" (___) ")")^_ + \
      ($++NF = "|" ____(__=$!_,___))^_ + \
      ($++NF = "|" __^(_<___?___:__))' ___="$__" 

done
```

> 

```
     1  -4  ^  (-3)  -0.015625            -0.015625
     2  -3  ^  (-3)  -0.037037037037037   -0.037037037037037
     3  -2  ^  (-3)  -0.125               -0.125
     4  -1  ^  (-3)  -1                   -1
     5  0   ^  (-3)  +inf                 +inf
     6  1   ^  (-3)  1                    1
     7  2   ^  (-3)  0.125                0.125
     8  3   ^  (-3)  0.037037037037037    0.037037037037037
     9  4   ^  (-3)  0.015625             0.015625
    10  5   ^  (-3)  0.008                0.008
    11  6   ^  (-3)  0.00462962962962963  0.00462962962962963
    12  7   ^  (-3)  0.00291545189504373  0.00291545189504373
    13  8   ^  (-3)  0.001953125          0.001953125
```

> 

```
    14  -4  ^  (-2)  0.0625               0.0625
    15  -3  ^  (-2)  0.111111111111111    0.111111111111111
    16  -2  ^  (-2)  0.25                 0.25
    17  -1  ^  (-2)  1                    1
    18  0   ^  (-2)  +inf                 +inf
    19  1   ^  (-2)  1                    1
    20  2   ^  (-2)  0.25                 0.25
    21  3   ^  (-2)  0.111111111111111    0.111111111111111
    22  4   ^  (-2)  0.0625               0.0625
    23  5   ^  (-2)  0.04                 0.04
    24  6   ^  (-2)  0.0277777777777778   0.0277777777777778
    25  7   ^  (-2)  0.0204081632653061   0.0204081632653061
    26  8   ^  (-2)  0.015625             0.015625
```

> 

```
    27  -4  ^  (-1)  -0.25                -0.25
    28  -3  ^  (-1)  -0.333333333333333   -0.333333333333333
    29  -2  ^  (-1)  -0.5                 -0.5
    30  -1  ^  (-1)  -1                   -1
    31  0   ^  (-1)  +inf                 +inf
    32  1   ^  (-1)  1                    1
    33  2   ^  (-1)  0.5                  0.5
    34  3   ^  (-1)  0.333333333333333    0.333333333333333
    35  4   ^  (-1)  0.25                 0.25
    36  5   ^  (-1)  0.2                  0.2
    37  6   ^  (-1)  0.166666666666667    0.166666666666667
    38  7   ^  (-1)  0.142857142857143    0.142857142857143
    39  8   ^  (-1)  0.125                0.125
```

> 

```
    40  -4  ^  (0)   1                    1
    41  -3  ^  (0)   1                    1
    42  -2  ^  (0)   1                    1
    43  -1  ^  (0)   1                    1
    44  0   ^  (0)   1                    1
    45  1   ^  (0)   1                    1
    46  2   ^  (0)   1                    1
    47  3   ^  (0)   1                    1
    48  4   ^  (0)   1                    1
    49  5   ^  (0)   1                    1
    50  6   ^  (0)   1                    1
    51  7   ^  (0)   1                    1
    52  8   ^  (0)   1                    1
```

> 

```
    53  -4  ^  ()    0.00390625           0.00390625
    54  -3  ^  ()    -0.037037037037037   -0.037037037037037
    55  -2  ^  ()    0.25                 0.25
    56  -1  ^  ()    -1                   -1
    57  0   ^  ()    1                    1
    58  1   ^  ()    1                    1
    59  2   ^  ()    4                    4
    60  3   ^  ()    27                   27
    61  4   ^  ()    256                  256
    62  5   ^  ()    3125                 3125
    63  6   ^  ()    46656                46656
    64  7   ^  ()    823543               823543
    65  8   ^  ()    16777216             16777216
```

> 

```
   (trimming out the -0 exponent ones since they're same as +0)
```

> 

```
    79  -4  ^  (1)   -4                   -4
    80  -3  ^  (1)   -3                   -3
    81  -2  ^  (1)   -2                   -2
    82  -1  ^  (1)   -1                   -1
    83  0   ^  (1)   0                    0
    84  1   ^  (1)   1                    1
    85  2   ^  (1)   2                    2
    86  3   ^  (1)   3                    3
    87  4   ^  (1)   4                    4
    88  5   ^  (1)   5                    5
    89  6   ^  (1)   6                    6
    90  7   ^  (1)   7                    7
    91  8   ^  (1)   8                    8
```

> 

```
    92  -4  ^  (2)   16                   16
    93  -3  ^  (2)   9                    9
    94  -2  ^  (2)   4                    4
    95  -1  ^  (2)   1                    1
    96  0   ^  (2)   0                    0
    97  1   ^  (2)   1                    1
    98  2   ^  (2)   4                    4
    99  3   ^  (2)   9                    9
   100  4   ^  (2)   16                   16
   101  5   ^  (2)   25                   25
   102  6   ^  (2)   36                   36
   103  7   ^  (2)   49                   49
   104  8   ^  (2)   64                   64
```

> 

```
   105  -4  ^  (3)   -64                  -64
   106  -3  ^  (3)   -27                  -27
   107  -2  ^  (3)   -8                   -8
   108  -1  ^  (3)   -1                   -1
   109  0   ^  (3)   0                    0
   110  1   ^  (3)   1                    1
   111  2   ^  (3)   8                    8
   112  3   ^  (3)   27                   27
   113  4   ^  (3)   64                   64
   114  5   ^  (3)   125                  125
   115  6   ^  (3)   216                  216
   116  7   ^  (3)   343                  343
   117  8   ^  (3)   512                  512
```

> ### ====================================

**UPDATE 1** ::: The shorter version that only does `x^x`, w/o binary squaring

```
jot 15 0 |
```

---

```
gawk 'func ___(__,_){$NF*=(__+=(""~__)*($++_+=!$_))>_?$_ ___(--__):_}!___()'
```

---

```
1
1
4
27
256
3125
46656
823543
16777216
387420489
10000000000
285311670611
8916100448256
302875106592253
11112006825558016
```

> ### ====================================

`awk` - a LOT of bytes (***123*** ?, per `Deadcode`), but it includes the ***full*** recursive binary squaring algorithm tailored for `x^x` without using ***any*** alphanumerics (other than unavoidable keywords like `function` and `return`) or the power (`^` | `**`) operator :

```
jot 14 | 

mawk 'function ____(__,___,_){return(___+=((_="")==___)*__)<(_+=++_)?\
           __+!+__:(___%_?__:!!_)*____(__*__,int(___/_))}$++NF=____($_)'
```

> 

```
0 1
1 1
2 4
3 27
4 256
5 3125
6 46656
7 823543
8 16777216
9 387420489
10 10000000000
11 285311670611
12 8916100448256
13 302875106592253
14 11112006825558016
```

Yes this is code golfing so mine is equivalent to Tiger Woods doing 10 strokes at a par 3 in Augusta, but unlike most other entries, this one scales nicely even for extremely large inputs, ***AND***, also being `POSIX`-compliant (not that it matters for golfing)

Comment: This appears to be **123 bytes**: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v8/rTQvuSQzP08hHgg04uN14kFYs7ootaS0KA8oEK9tq6ERb6ukpGlrC@RpagGxjQZQVFs7XtMeKK2oHR9vBVKoGg/kWikqgtWADQPSOpl5JSBJ/XhNzVoVbW0/N1uwpEq85v//hiYA "AWK – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$5\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.12 bytes

```
ZOA*P
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6Fkuj_B21AiBsqNCChaYQBgA)

Note: the built-in solution would have been just one character: `^` or `@` (either would work).

##### Explanation

```python
ZOA*P # Implicit input
ZO    # Wrap the input in a list
  A*  # Repeat it input times
    P # Take the product of this list
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 73 bytes

```fortran
integer(selected_int_kind(32))::n
read*,n;print*,product([(n,j=1,n)]);end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpLDkBAEAX3bmHXIyPx2REnERHRbfzySBvnHxJ2laqaDvU6IHXTByEs8OJE6ZJdRi/cv6LfFjCVhTFVhUhl4MSiPvVNiT314Hv01BLs2uQWpjO1gEP8D/PthPC5PHsA).

Uses a larger integer type because the implicit integer type overflows doing `10**10`. This solution can compute results up to `170141183460469231731687303715884105727`.
We make an inline anonymous array of `n`s : `[(n,j=1,n)]`, take the `product()`, and `print` the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 3 bytes (6 nibbles)

```
/,$*_@
```

```
/,$*_@
/           # fold from right over
 ,$         # 1..input
   *        # multiplying
     @      # result-so-far with
    _       # input
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 8 bytes

```
|$+[*~]~
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7C%24%2B%5B*%7E%5D%7E&inputs=5)

I posted the 9-byte answer and immediately found a way to improve it. This method uses `$` to swap the top of the stack with the existing value in memory (0) then increments to get 1. It otherwise follows the same logic.

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 9 bytes

```
|s=1[*~]~
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7Cs%3D1%5B*%7E%5D%7E&inputs=5)

## Explanation

```
|            parse input
 s           save input to memory
  =1         set top of stack to 1
    [  ]~    loop n times where n is the value in memory
     *~      multiply the top of the stack by the value in memory
             (print implicitly)
```

Comment: How many more bytes would it take to work with an input of 0?

Comment: @Deadcode depends if you think [0^0=1](http://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7C%5B0%2Bq%5D%24%2B%5B*~%5D~&inputs=0)

Comment: Rattle itself thinks [0^0=1](http://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7Cse~&inputs=0), so that is indeed Rattle's own exponentiation operator reimplemented (for nonnegative integer input) without using it, in 13 bytes.

Comment: @Deadcode that's right, it would be 13 bytes if it had to handle x=0 (possibly less if someone thinks of a more elegant solution). However 0<x for this question. Good observation though, I never considered the 0^0 case when implementing exponentiation in Rattle but I'm glad it ended up being 1 because that's the right answer imo

Comment: If you had read [my Nibbles answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259490/17216) or [my comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119854/raise-integer-x-to-power-x-without-exponentiation-built-ins/259490?noredirect=1#comment571926_119854) you'd know that I know it's 0<x for this question. That doesn't change that it's an interesting extension of this question. Should we always ignore such items of interest just because they go beyond the question? There's no other place on the site where this could go, since the same question but 0≤x would get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Deadcode agreed, always good to take it a step further. Unfortunately taking it further makes my answer 13 bytes instead of 8 because it just adds an if case, maybe I should see if I can find a better way

Comment: Sorry for my over-defensive reply :-) I do think this could have been (or maybe still could be?) fixed in the Rattle language itself, which would let the 8 byte program handle 0. Is there any useful reason Rattle should loop infinitely when given a loop iteration count of 0? Does it need to keep doing this to maintain compatibility with existing Rattle programs?

Comment: @Deadcode you make a very good point, it is a little annoying that it loops infinitely here. Maybe an infinite loop should only occur if the argument is explicitly 0 (e.g. `]0`), and loop 0 times if implicitly 0 (e.g. `]~` where the value at the pointer is 0). Currently `]0` is equivalent to while(true)

Answer (score 2):

## [vemf](https://selaere.github.io/vemf/doc/docs.html), <s>6</s> 3 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to language creator*

```
┴‼*
```

[try it online](https://selaere.github.io/vemf/wasm/index.html?code=M8ETKg) (uses 3 as example)

### Explanation:

```
┴‼*
┴   ' do this function with the same value for both arguments
 ‼  '   repeat each element of [left] the-element-at-the-corresponding-index-of-[right] times
  * ' multiply elements of resulting list
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 20 bytes

```powershell
@($n)*$n-join"*"|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqdgq2D230FDJU9TSyVPNys/M09JS6kmM7Xi/38A)

**Explanation**

```powershell
@($n)*$n-join"*"|iex    # full command
@($n)                   # array consisting of single element
*$n                     # multiply the array element x times
-join"*"                # joins all elements with * separating (3*3*3)
|iex                    # executes the provided expression
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```go
func(n int)int{p,i:=1,0
for;i<n;i++{p*=n}
return p}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7BCoJAGITv-xQ_ndz8C02K0HwH7xGxiCs_5e-yrV3EJ-kiQQ_l27SWh2EOM_Mxr3fdjhMYVd5UXUGjiAU1prVuu9KNW4mnsqDzT-f05jgluuMyYCB20qs3SGkeYyR0azM6cUZh2Jt1zoOwlessgxmWaTFPf_xAQi_oAWkO58tM2WGCezxgHA0zCK5Ic2gV-0e-2IvC-t6dA0LQAUkpBrFwx_HvXw)

- -2 by @The Thonnu: anonymous function

Comment: I think you can save 2 by making it anonymous: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY7BCoJAGITv-xQ_ndz8C02K0HwH7xGxiCs_5e-yrV3EJ-kiQQ_l27SWh2EOM_Mxr3fdjhMYVd5UXUGjiAU1prVuu9KNW4mnsqDzT-f05jgluuMyYCB20qs3SGkeYyR0azM6cUZh2Jt1zoOwlessgxmWaTFPf_xAQi_oAWkO58tM2WGCezxgHA0zCK5Ic2gV-0e-2IvC-t6dA0LQAUkpBrFwx_HvXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 4 bytes

```
×´⥊˜
```

[Try it](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkMOXwrTipYrLnAoKRsKoIDLigL8z4oC/NeKAvzbigL8xMA==)

```
  ⥊˜ # a list of N Ns
×´   # product
```

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, <s>29</s> 26 bytes

Saved 3c

```rust
|x|(0..x).fold(1,|a,_|a*x)
```

```rust
|x|(0..x).map(|_|x).product()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 2 bytes

```
ř∏
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FkuPznzU0b-kOCm5GCqyYJURlzGXKZcZl6EBRAQA)

```
ř   Replicate
 ∏  Product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
g;?j₎×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@59ubZ/1qKnv8PT//03/RwEA)

#### Explanation

```
          Example input: 5
g         Group: [5]
 ;?       Pair with the Input: [[5], 5]
   j₎     Juxtapose [5] 5 times: [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
     ×    Multiply
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
ri_a*:*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UGZ@oZaX1/78pAA)

**Explanation**

```
ri       e# Read an int from input
  _      e# Duplicate it
   a*    e# Put the copy in the array and repeat it that many times
     :*  e# Take the product of the array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <strike>24</strike> <strike>23</strike> <strike>26</strike> 22 bytes

This is my first attempt writing a recursive macro in dc. I am sure it is a sub-optimal solution which can be improved a lot.

```
dsr1+[lrr1-d1<F*]dsFxp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#M/ufUlxkqB2dU1RkqJtiaOOmFZtS7FZR8P8/AA)

**Edit:** Thanks **eush77**! -4 bytes.

Comment: Does not work for `x=1`.

Comment: You can shave off two bytes by replacing `lr` sequences at the end with two `d`s at the beginning.

Comment: Actually, you don't need that. Just increment the top of the stack before calling for the first time. This way you will end up with `x` copies of `x` on the stack (and `1` of course), and `x` multiplications thereafter. So the ending can just be plain `dsFxp`.

Comment: @eush77 I was about to say that removing second `lr` wouldn't work here. It's my first time golfing in a stack-based language, so it feels very unusual. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 13 bytes

```
{[*] $_ xx$_}
```

`$_ xx $_` evaluates to a list of `$_` copies of `$_` (`$_` being the argument to the anonymous function), and then `[*]` reduces that list with multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 6 bytes

```
ri_m*,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@UGZ@rpfP/vykA)

```
ri       e# Read integer
  _      e# Duplicate
   m*    e# Cartesian power. The first argument is interpreted as a range
     ,   e# Number of elements. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>49</s> 46 bytes

*Golfed 3 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```
.+
1;$&$*1;$&$*1
{`1(?=1*;(1+);.)
$1
}`1$

\G1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@6@nzWVoraKmogUluaoTDDXsbQ21rDUMtTWt9TS5VAy5ahMMVbi4YtwN//83BgA)

Supports positive integers just as stated in the challenge.

Comment: I think you can save a byte by using `.+` `1;$&$*1;$&$*` instead of your first four lines.

Comment: And shave three more off by using `\G1` instead of your last three lines.

Comment: @Neil Ah, `\G`, that's a neat trick

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 22

```
#(apply *(repeat % %))
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 17 bytes

```
{product([_]*_1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#y03MzFOo5uJMU7BViPlfXVCUn1KaXKIRHR@rFW@oWfufs6AoM69EoyCxqDjVM68kNT21SKMkWVOhRiFNQ1NTIS2/SKEkmav2vxGXMZcJlymXGZehAQA)

It's an anonymous function that takes it's input from the stream.

Explanation:

```
{product([_]*_1)}
{               } /* An anonymous function */
         [_]      /* An array containing the input value */
            *_1   /* repeated times the input value */
 product(      )  /* Product of all values in the array */
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 58 bytes

```
@set n=1
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @set/an*=%1
@echo %n%
```

Only works for single-digit inputs due to 32-bit arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

## MacOS Bash, 18

```bash
jot -s* -b$1 $1|bc
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S8svUihJLS5JTixOVcjMU6g21NMzMqi1VkjJ51IAgoKizLySNAUl1RQFXTsFJQUVmGKwbHFqiYKuLkLwf1Y@UKBYS0E3ScVQQcWwJin5f0p@Xup/AA).

Also runs on Linux if you install the `jot` utility:

```bash
sudo apt install athena-jot
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainf*ck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 148 bytes

```
,[->+>+<<]>>[-<<+>>]++++++++[<------<------>>-]<[->>+>>+<<<<]>>[-<<+>>]>>-[-<<<<<[>[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<<<-]>>[-<<+>>]>>>]<<<++++++++[-<<++++++>>]<<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#VU3JDcAwCBuIup9@LS@C2H8MCimJVH8wPiAvh0xGhuQgTQobOLEwQ0Kw4pXvwq9SXtOCy7@DaHu5VZv1pNXS@YPNl35nPi8)

No built-ins ;)

**How it works**

```
,                                       - get ascii input
[->+>+<<]                               - duplicate input
>>[-<<+>>]                              - shift inputs left to start
++++++++[<------<------>>-]             - convert ascii into input numbers
<[->>+>>+<<<<]                          - get loop intervals (same as input #)
>>[-<<+>>]                              - shift input back again
>>-[-<<<<<[>[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]<<<-]>>  - iterated addition (multiplication)
[-<<+>>]>>>                             - Shift output back into input
]<<<++++++++[-<<++++++>>]<<.            - convert final output to ascii
```

In a nutshell, this works by multiplying `x` (the input) by itself `x` times. (a.k.a. iterating iterated addition). The net result is x^x.

**I/O**

The program takes a single ASCII input, and processes it as it's *ASCII index minus 48*. The *minus 48* is to normalize inputs of actual numbers (`4` becomes `52` -> `52-48` -> `4`). To input a number higher than 9, use the next corrosponging ASCII character (`:` -> `58-48` -> `10`). The program ouputs in a similar fashion.

**Test I/O**

```
INPUT > PROCESSED INPUT >> OUTPUT > TRANSLATED OUTPUT
1 > 1 >> 1 > 1
2 > 2 >> 4 > 4
3 > 3 >> K > 27
```

Since there are no printable ASCII characters after an input of 3, it can only print numbers *in theory*. Though, you can check all inputs do in fact work on visualizers such as [this](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/).

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 9 bytes

```
prod(seq(Ans,A,1,Ans
```

Input is from `Ans`, output is stored in `Ans`.

Run with `5:prgmNAME:Ans` (5 or other input) for visual output.

Generates a list of `Ans` copies of `Ans`, then finds the product.

Answer (score 1):

## [Common Lisp](http://www.clisp.org/), <s>59 42</s> 40 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(x)(apply'*(fill(make-list x)x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcwxDoAgDEDR3VOw2Zo4qCeqCEljwSqY4OmROLv@5H0rnLRCcvk03oC/o818xApCYd0ICgKpytMP4FkEAu1ubCabggURK2IHenHMnyWRtpn@4vwXl3Z4AQ)

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB/Octave, 23 bytes

```
@(n)(prod(n*ones(n,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 32 bytes

```
f=lambda g,z=1:z>g or g*f(g,z+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIV2nytbQqsouXSG/SCFdK00DKKBtqPm/oCgzr0QjTcNEU/M/AA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You don't need to count the `f=` part, so you can shorten your submission to [30 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFdp8rW0KrKLl0hv0ghXStNAyigbaj5v6AoM69EI03DVFPzPwA).

Comment: @Steadybox The `f=` part does need to be counted, because it's recursive, so it relies upon the function being named `f` in order to work properly

Comment: @musicman523 Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
G*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fXev/fzMA)

#### Explanation

```
G*
G  # Do input - 1 times
 *  # Multiply with input
```

Answer (score 1):

### Julia 0.6, 18 bytes

```
x->prod(x*ones(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 5 bytes

```
*/@$~
```

- `$~` shapes the argument into a list with as many items as it is, eg, `3` becomes `3 3 3`.
- `@` pipes the result into...
- `*/` reduce by multiplication

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0FL30Gljis1OSNfQSNNyUBTwUjBWMFUwez/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), 16 bytes

```
ns<l1-[>l*<1-]>u
```

Being forced to use multiple stacks costs so many bytes...

[Try it online!](http://lylang.herokuapp.com/?program=ns%3Cl1-[%3El*%3C1-]%3Eu&input=6)

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), <strike>40</strike> <s>25</s> 22 bytes

```
%@![~!~1A]%1A[1A~W~]%:
```

-15 from Dion's improved input methods.
-3 after modifying first loop to happen x+1 times.

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/v1.1?code=%25%40!%5B%7E!%7E1A%5D%251A%5B1A%7EW%7E%5D%25%3A&input=4)

#### Explanation

```
%@                    Gets multi digit input
![~!~1A]%             x gets cloned x+1 times in the stack
1A[1A~W~]%:           multiplies top 2 numbers x-1 times
```

Comment: 1+ wins this time!

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive not with the updated input methods... Razetime, come to the rescue! :D

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive and they get MAWP... 25 bytes. https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP/?code=%25%40!1A%5B1A~!~%5D%25_1A%5B1A~W~%5D%25%3A&input=13

Comment: Dang! That's unfair!! @Dion

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive Well, a) I made the changes without seeing this first, and b) Multi-digit input was extremely annoying, so this was something that had to be done. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Dion That was meant to be a joke... At some point though 1+ will become a subset of MAWP, and it becomes completely unfair.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111739/discussion-between-highlyradioactive-and-dion).

Comment: @Dion 27 bytes in 1+. Let's see if I can golf it further...

Comment: @Dion 1+ is at 24 bytes now!! I spent way too much effort on this... But finally, I won!!!

Comment: ...Lemme see if I can take some more bytes off my 1+ answer. It's already pretty close to optimal afaik... I'm gonna write an auto-optimizer for 1+ (input ungolfed code, output golfed-to-optimal code. Can't support `#` and functions for obvious reasons, but is otherwise fully functional.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Integral](https://github.com/nph278/integral), 5 Bytes

```
v↕♦▼e
```

[Try it!](https://nph278.github.io/integral/?code=dhIEH2U&input=2%0A%0A3%0A%0A5%0A%0A6%0A%0A10)

### Explanation

```
v↕    Multiply two items of the stack, to be evaluated
  ♦   Swap the top two items
   ▼  Decrement
    e Evaluate ↕ that many times
```

Answer (score 1):

### Google Sheets, 24

Input A1.

```
=DECIMAL(1&REPT(0,A1),A1
```

Is base conversion ok? If not, here's one at 26 (but it's really boring):

```
=PRODUCT(SEQUENCE(A1,1,A1,
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 43+1 bytes

```java
s->{int i=0,t=s;for(;++i<s;t*=s);return t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZAxc8IwDIV3/4o3OqUE2l5ZTJhYmRi5DiY2YEhszla46@Xy24MSOjeDBumT3nunq37o@dXcelFWOiXstPOtEAJwnmw86dJi23ILVMGfYSTPkTKFxQJ7io5npxBxDHQBXSx0PDe15R3tDaKlJnq@7rgSaXIltjAoIPo037SjpCuW71QkxTJSzWZunRS9FWzxugaprhdqiHRvjhUr/Ak9gjOoOa985Tj8DOYpa8UYd/@byNZ5aCi/M6bKS5Mb@Zll6j/@NcG/J/hqgn8sh4XxJV3/BA)

Overflows for `10`, so all `int`s need to be changed to `long` a the cost of +1. This has been done for the TIO link.

I didn't think I could beat the `IntStream` though!

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 9 bytes

```
¿(:;|:)∑*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////0H4NK@saK81HHRO1/v83@q@bUQQA)

I said I'd count Keg's victories over 1+ as victories for mawp, so it's 2-1 to mawp!

Comment: No way! (15chrs)

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive stop vandalising my answer.

Comment: stop 2-1ing. (15)

Comment: Who's post is this? Huh, looks like it's mine. _Leave it alone_

Comment: @HighlyRadioactive I flagged you for vandalizing a single post 10 times in a row. Stop it, or your account will get suspended.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```rust
|x|(0..x).fold(1,|a,_|a*x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XczBCoMwDIDhe58i85QMJ62iDDc89jWGMMsEV4dWJlifvWsvZXhL@JJ/WmbjlIZ322sk2BiA6WaDzq4WeZatlKlxeKJIbZs@bHteyQHQje2M@bdwe5cNqhokse@rmzpfkH7TuIj8SnBpIAwslD9Tr82gT5jkNWx7koLCnHzsn4pIxZHKSOWRqkjVkQSPJnjA3f0A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 18 bytes

```factor
[ dup <array> Π ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQWFSUWFmskJ1alJeao5CbWJKhV5qXmZyfkqpQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JgzcVl@j9aIaW0QMEGrMVO4dwChdj/yYk5OQp6/wE)

```
        ! 5
dup     ! 5 5
<array> ! { 5 5 5 5 5 }
Π       ! 3125
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 45 bytes

```cpp
int e(int x,int i=0){return++i<x?x*e(x,i):x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsMgFETXeooPXUSTFpKtmvYi3Yix5UOiwSgIIWe32s28xTBvzL4/zKrdtxR0ESxrme8tcR75GWxMwQ0DqvzKvWW14iLLq9zQmTUtFhT6IwartyelbbZpdIzTk5KPD/D3IcwwyQoF0yih2jgl5IiLEManCEq1Y97YvV0n6VV@)

Answer (score 1):

## [FunStack](https://github.com/dloscutoff/funstack) alpha, 14 bytes

```
Product Repeat
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/funstack)!

#### Explanation

```
        Repeat  Given one argument N, create a list of N copies of N
Product         Return the product of that list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ReRegex](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ReRegex), 55 bytes

```
#import math
(_+)p(_+)_/$1*($1p$2)/p_\b//#input
p#input
```

I/O as Unary _'s.

### Explanation

Implements exponentiation by repeating the argument itself times. This is done by transforming, for instance `____p__` into `____*(____p_)`. Decrementing the right, and pulling the left out.
Finally, any instance of `p_` has the p removed, as x^1==x.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otSk1Prfj/XzkztyC/qEQhN7Ekg0sjXluzAETE66sYammoGBaoGGnqF8THJOnrK2fmFZSWcBVA6P//40HgfyoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-lgmp`, 82 bytes

Uses GMP because everyone needs to be able to do `100**100`.

```c
#import<gmp.h>
f(x,a,y)int*a;{mpz_init_set_ui(a,y=x);for(;--y;)mpz_mul_ui(a,a,x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BboMwEETvfMUoUSRDlipp1V4c8iFNI2RMoJYwIOJUJIhfj7suhx68smfGb1antdber43tu8Edatu/fB@jSoyk6B6b1iVKTrZ/5KY1Lr9eXH4zgq1sjGXVDUKm6V3GIWBvzeIpYm/2/BdWmVb8dKaMMUVAkNTpnE3YE14Jb4R3wgdhvwuHxw4zISkkhwPTYZQR30NTkSkZLBTb7YJjXSQFgev@Xrx83g9cUonVpkR2xOaz/GpXgfifClzdXNQgFmWOZv/UVaPqq08bZvwC)

Comment: Of course this challenge doesn't require it, but it costs +1 byte to make \$0^0=1\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/dboMwDIXveQqrU6UEzEY3bTcpfZD9CJlAWCQCCNIJinj1ZcmYtDv7nGN/tkwbKZ2702boR3tuzHD/eYkUm5Fw4bqzMYnVDLdCd9oWU22Lq2aEJy5UP7Iln8WSpoKHhLm2u0k4c7E5PwyGdMe@el1xWCOAINHbR75ChnBCeER4QnhGePFtkLIMNoS4FD4cdlqYReTrACtzElCeKZn0re4VI/7wV8XEvZMkO8SnWVwi@CN@O/9TMYwerdjhWEF@geNr9d4dAuc/FWiyrWlku7JFm/uWqqVmcmnrd/wA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 16 bytes

```
$=>[∏@.of:<=&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?QYSh5h)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 17 bytes

```julia
!x=prod(_->x,1:x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HCtqAoP0UjXteuQsfQqkLzv0NxRn65gqLZfwA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
⁻{×
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWyx417q4-PH1JcVJyMVRowUJTCAMA)

```
Wọp
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWS8Mf7u4tWFKclFwMFVmw0BTCAAA)

##### Explanation

```python
⁻{×  # Implicit input
⁻    # Decrement the input
 {   # Repeat that many times:
  ×  #  Multiply TOS with input
     # Implicit output
```

```python
Wọp  # Implicit input
W    # Wrap the input in a list
 ọ   # Repeat it input number of times
  p  # Product of this list
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 38 Bytes

```php
for($p=1;$i++<$argn;)$p*=$argn;echo$p;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@ztbT@n5ZfpKFSYGtorZKprW0DFrbWVCnQsoUwU5Mz8lUKrP//BwA)

Comment: Drop that `,$i=0`.

Comment: @Christoph as I write the answer there was a condition that no error should be throw

Comment: There's no version of PHP that doesn't ignore E_NOTICE by default. Only with E_NOTICE it is thrown ;) And you really should track your score using `<s></s>` like everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
lyX"p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@59TGaFU8P@/CQA)

#### Explanation

Example values with input `4`.

```
l    % Push 1
     % STACK: 1
y    % Implicit input. Duplicate from below
     % STACK: 4, 1, 4
X"   % Replicate along two dimensions. Gives a row vector
     % STACK: [4, 4, 4, 4]
p    % Product of array. Implicitly display.
     % STACK: 256
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 12 bytes

```
:[a|q=q*a}?q
```

Explanation:

```
:   Get the integer
[a|     Start a FOR loop, for x iterations
q=q*a   Multiply q (starts out as 1) by our value, then store that in q
}       End loop
?q      Print q
```

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, <strike>34</strike> 33 bytes

```
,$n,$p=$args,1;1..$n|%{$p*=$n};$p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#U0myrf6vo5Kno1Jgq5JYlF6sY2htqKenklejWq1SoGWrkldrrVLwv5bLSMdYx1THTMfQACijppKkoBJf@x8A)

Previous version

```
,$n,$ofs=$args,'*';''+@($n)*$n|iex
```

Comment: Using `param($a)'1'+"*$a"*$a|iex` works too, more in line with the other `String->eval` answers, nice to see other PowerShell golfers around,

Comment: Your noteworthy code snippet may be transformed to the next one `param($a)"$a*"*$a+1|iex`.

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 34 bytes

```
i,k;f(x){for(i=k=x;--i;)x*=k;i=x;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@pk22dplGhWZ2WX6SRaZttW2Gtq5tprVmhZZttnQnk1f7PzCtRyE3MzNPQ5KrmUgCCgiKgUJqGkmpKTB4CK@kopGkYaYJIYzBpCibNNDWtuWr/AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Fourier, 19 bytes

```
1~YI~X(Y*X~Yi^~i)Yo
```

[**Try it on FourIDE!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=MX5ZSX5YKFkqWH5ZaV5-aSlZbw)

Multiplies Y by the input X number of times and then outputs Y.

FYI, the standard way to do this would be

```
I~XPXo
```

Where `P` is the power function

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 51 bytes

```
def f(x,i=0):i=i or x;return x*f(x,i-1)if i>1else x
```

A little bit more verbose than @xnor's clever way of `eval`, but uses recursion

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 24 bytes

```groovy
{a->r=1;a.times{r*=a};r}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 56 bytes

```
readIO
x=i
readIO
a=i
b=1
lbla
a-1
b*x
if a a
printInt b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@1@Umpji6c9VYZvJBWUmAplJtoZcOUk5iVyJuoZcSVoVXJlpCokKiVwFRZl5JZ55JQpJ////N/pvaAAA)
Loops through repeated multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 76 bytes

```
(({})){({}<(({}))>[()])}{}{{}({}<>)({<({}[()])><>({})<>}{}<><{}>)([][()])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#NYvBDQAxDMLWSQa4H2KRqpMgZk@TnvpBFoaKkDPViR@5IndaljwtM4SGWxOcEegxkNuu/R5V3wE)

This is an extremely inefficient algorithm, so don't try inputs larger than 7.

Explanation:

```
#Duplicate the input
(({}))

#Make *n* copies of the input
{({}<(({}))>[()])}{}

#While the stack has more than one element on it,
{{}

  #Multiply the top two elements
  ({}<>)({<({}[()])><>({})<>}{}<><{}>)

  #Push stack-height minus one to keep the loop running
  ([][()])

#Endwhile
}

#Pop a zero off the main stack, implicitly display the number left on the stack
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/L3viathan/Aceto), 33 bytes

We have quite a bit of wasted space, so I'm sure we could get rid of a few more bytes.

```
=|
0*v
ds<

 MDL
 &_d
id!L
rDM@xp
```

The bottom half (except for the `xp`) reads the input, and puts it that many times on the stack, as an integer, i.e. '3' -> [3, 3, 3]. I really need a builtin for that..

The top half calculates the product by swapping the top two elements, checking if the top element is zero, otherwise multiplying the top two elements, and so on. `xp` prints.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 16 bytes

```
n->prod(x=1,n,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#DcmxCcAwDATAVR5XEsgQDWBPEwRp3ka4yPZKrr3AQLHPneuWd7jRqBUrhf@4wS/DzodHaGjoE80QQlWtDw)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 9 JShell, 44 bytes

```
x->IntStream.range(0,x).reduce(1,(a,b)->a*x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk9#fVDLasMwELz7KxZDQAqySFrSQwOBHgstOZieSg8bWzYqtiT0CDZtvl2VUx/SlnQuEvuYmR3ZG209vOMRefCy401QlZda8eU2k7@bzluB/dTKTDh0soKqQ@fgGaWCjwwS5rrz6NNz1LIGY3UlnCNPWrUvCu24N8Ki1xYaBl0qwkDn7Qnl6LzouQ6eGyuVb0i@KDY1fMKiXqicwcCg4WhMNz64iZMMlG7P66fsmoc@OSSlT3zt6xugbd1/kp0i@aMywSfRffDpk88K16aLH7icbtKdszI4uP@jfTY8JxSHYjddVH7nbFG1gqzYQLkVdagEWTOC7ECLHS4HGi8pGEyL3KB14hyKoxcmTnM8pxhv4m3cxLu4Xn0B)

Notes:

- The imports are not included in the score since they are not required with the default JShell configuration (there are a number of packages imported by the default JShell startup script).
- Since TIO doesn't have JShell, a [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/) program is provided that demonstrates the function, but has been changed to use longs so that 10 to the tenth doesn't overflow, at the expense of one extra byte.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
u*GH*]QQ1
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2aGH%2a%5DQQ1&input=0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A3%0A5%0A6%0A10&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 4

This took me a while to figure out in pyth, but I finally got there:

```
*F*]
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2AF%2A%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5&debug=0).

#### Explanation

```
   ]Q     # create one-item list (of implicit input)
  *  Q    # repeat (implicit input) times
*F        # reduce list over multiplication
```

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 52

```
proc P n {incr p;time {set p [expr $p*$n]} $n;set p}
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/ANYFD45508)

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 50

```
proc P n {time {lappend L $n} $n;expr [join $L *]}
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/NXE45109)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 36 bytes

```powershell
$a="$args";$b=1;1..$a|%{$b=$b*$a};$b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXRVkklsSi9WMlaJcnW0NpQT08lsUa1GshRSdJSSawFCv///98MAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7, 37 bytes

Full Program:

```
s,x=1,input();exec('s*=x;')*x;print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v1inwtZQJzOvoLREQ9M6tSI1WUO9WMu2wlpdU6vCuqAoM69Eofj/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 18 + 3 (-v flag) bytes

```
:l(?v:
=?v*>l1
n;>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3ypHw77MisvWvkzLLseQK8/a7v///7plCpYA)

-v flag to put our number on the stack allows for bigger numbers with little over head.

## Explination

```
:l(?v:

:l(     | Copies the stack top, adds the length of the stack then compares.
   ?v:  | Checks if the compare was true,
        |  if not then copy the stack top and loop, else move down.

=?v*>l1 

    >l1 | Move the direction right, add the length of the stack, add 1 to the stack.
=?v*    | Compare the length of the stack to 1,
        |  if the stack is 1 item move down, else multiply the top 2 stack items.

n;>

n;>     | Moves the directions right, then prints the top stack item as a number then ends the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 34 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from Range `[A1]` and outputs `[A1^A1]` to the VBE immediate window

```vba
n=1:For i=1To[A1]:n=n*[A1]:Next:?n
```

### Interesting Version, 40 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from Range `[A1]` and outputs `[A1^A1]` by method of worksheet manipulation to the VBE immediate window

```vba
[A1].Resize([A1],1)=[A1]:?[PRODUCT(A:A)]
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 44 bytes

```php
<?=array_product(array_fill(1,$argn,$argn));
```

not the shortest solution; but it might trigger ideas for other languages.

Run as pipe with `-R` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b209ebd20025cc880070453e71f2d79626a2b76).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 5 bytes

```
&tCP#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/1@txDlA@f///6YA)**

```
         \ Implicit: Input on stack                       [3]
&tC      \ Push (input - 1) extra copies of input         [3, 3, 3]
   P     \ Calculate product                              [3, 3, 3, 27]
    #    \ Output result                                  PRINT 27
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>71</s> 62 bytes

```
listen to N
X's0
P's1
while N-X
let X be+1
let P be*N-0

say P
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 37 bytes

```python
lambda x:reduce(lambda a,b:a*b,[x]*x)
```

For Python 3, add

```python
from functools import reduce
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Aussie++](https://github.com/zackradisic/aussieplusplus/), 94 bytes

Not that there's an exponentiation builtin in the first place.

```
THE HARD YAKKA FOR f IS(x)<I RECKON a =1;I RECKON _ IS A WALKABOUT FROM[0TO x)a =a *x;BAIL a;>
```

Tested in commit 9522366. All whitespace included is necessary.

Just a straightforward golf of [intPow from Math.aussie](https://github.com/bbrk24/miscellany/blob/master/Math.aussie#L93).