# Quartic Summation

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic

## Guidelines

#### Task

Given two non-negative integers, find the sum of both numbers... to the power of 4.

---

#### Examples

`2, 3 -> 97` (2^4 + 3^4 = 97)

`14, 6 -> 39712` (14^4 + 6^4 = 39712)

`0, 25 -> 390625` (0^4 + 25^4 = 390625)

---

#### Rules

- You will only ever receive two non-negative integers as input (bonus points if you get it to work with negative integer input).
- You can take the input however you would like (arrays, list, two separate arguments, comma-separated string)
- You can either output your answer as a number or a string.
- As this is code golf, the shortest answer in bytes will win.

Comment: You say `two positive integers`, but one of the test cases contains a `0`. Also, there's not many languages that would have trouble with negative integers, given the result is the same as if they were positive.

Comment: "positive integers" might be confusing for non english people. In French, 0 is both positive and negative.

Comment: I've downvoted this challenge for the following reason: it is a fairly trivial, yet non-essential (such as Hello, World!) and I doubt that any interesting answers will be produced.

Comment: Downvoted for the same reason as @cairdcoinheringaahing.

Comment: @Damien Interesting! In the US (at least), `0` is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: Upvoted because sometimes trivial challenges are fun

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Just because it is trivial, does not mean it is a bad challenge? Take a look at the CP-1610 answer, I would definitely call that interesting. It has produced interesting solutions.

Comment: @Amorris That's a reason to upvote that answer, not a reason to not downvote the question.

Comment: The mark of a good question here is that nearly *all* of the answers are interesting.

Comment: @Amorris 2 things: 1) I don't think it is a bad challenge, simply that it adds nothing new to the site, and so, in my eyes, is downvote-worthy 2) I'd recommend not accepting an answer, especially not this early, as people view code golf as more of a competition within languages, rather than between them.

Comment: I'd prefer if this challenge didn't require zero to be handled, because not doing so lets me save bytes :P

Comment: Your challenges really split the community.

Comment: @user202729 Sure do. First it's too difficult, next it's too hard, next you only want input validation. Most challenges are not even challenges anymore.

Comment: @Zionmyceliaadamancy This challenge should be given another chance. Although trivial in mainstream languages, it's interesting in certain esoteric languages, or languages that are mainstream but not designed to do arithmetic.

Answer (score 7):

## Regex  `m` (PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35 or later</sup></sub>), 10 bytes

```
^(?*x+){4}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbLbttGFF1XXzFmAHuGGqei_IgjmjZcW4AF2HKgyGgaxyVoaiQRpoYEOYwfqbb9gG676aabAvmgdNkv6Z0HKcpSUcGihnfuPfc5Z_z71zCNi1x-_UkYfr2xtuM0zFh7-8C6_TZ4NWLjiDP07nTQbfunV2dd_7rfG_o_9s6G5-ig8SriYVyMGDpURq-nR41wGmTIT29ukYcG1g8PD_d3O8VPT08fhtP9hyn-sxDj7YO_fsbH9mOTfNmda8Hf370lL3UtiuzU89Om49Yc5SKL-ER6WsiiBKQsmB2t6B01Ii5QCkvhsyxLMhwmPBdIRWnPWJ4HE0bQl1yMOp0QNNDhITJiuVRyxkexizImiowjx52vYMr3MBkxiu6SJEaJNw7iXMIqNwbupr23f-s2EHyiMcKqYP6EGQzfaGGNg3XFr0_PTwYHNjGbFOXRM0vGuAr8-1JS0yeEKC_ygxN0rJMIk0KgDqoSJTI9S5khFUEHWS-SV8aWBVbWJ26Rqh5jmJapzqQqSmPeKHgeTTgboTjhE_0IeP7AMlcVbPbkh0EcQxgmd_Pm38VJeI_skKLPSTRC9igQAdROFkkukechLHdssrnAIAa72aw60zKdmQURxwCgAkxvYBBixnFKtp1br-XqFPR0oDT0LHzcsVxYNb1U_1gEH5_Cd4OAvADEnbYvoKlgK-EnsFDQdaCIp4WQ5ioxaCGyM1a-zwIRTn2Vi71Ya7SM5UUsqG6Baw7a-97HrpKMxzmDTcgXUpiI6ZKCnXxmoQAr0wk4cKX_WRrFDJuheP9uOCBp-Dr0IVhMqMH42B1c-cPu4LLXPxl2z0px98Ow2z_rnqFfjODy-mLYu-j1uxRtqijNr4mtRRYzvZHBSJpu1M-Hehq9WjG8lfr48B4I5o-zZOangRAs4ziDue9fX1wYgLoNHGbBHgWUtVx56_YNLF5BgQyqoSwhaG1S6brJewmgXcXRLKqDbDvErSmNWCr-VyljYZHlUcLXKiq34yRDim-eq1kGDomBpLE-2hGnehqJW56Bsj3PBIFcchLe-sS3wPWz57hqS1m8llyCiee1CJKeI14wd4EATmEKpVvNnvlir4oqTXJQWPJc2nL24IM9RRyaFIgkMk7NWKKmNCbusp0kSpC-gKtOnyI1yWPUclc1wA-WodoE2g-9C3EODTVxwKZ8NpEDXy7dO2QNxg0oNZvyMpMlW1aYIwY0vy62heeZdlzzutbXfOltxmYwDjgHRVWxrcctKBv0S4UjMTSaDKucgrIUfBkYqgdKutJwlY_wFgUsKVVBlBWWJFvjs06Hq7LfQeHuXa3uSZZfjXe5D-ifX39DQJuanFV4laamuuUTqg53naegQyrllvpbMAOszWGoVU4Gr1EPW2hz03jY8AyTDQZXA79_dXkyPD0ny1WpkVPJwCIrWA1btnbJZilRk9-aG3H-XyQFpMYYXmSxSn5aoXon9ftEbwK_VtedjhsuXv0f1B_fdtp0p-Hs0v1Gi7b3Go03jR3qqKVDYYvu0j26T9_QA_pWyh2HOm1t-y8) - PCRE2 v10.40+

Takes its input in comma-delimited unary, as a concatenation of strings of `x` characters whose lengths represent the numbers, separated by `,` characters. (Bonus: The number of arguments is variable, not just 2.) Returns its output as the number of ways the regex can match. (The rabbit emoji indicates this output method. It can yield outputs bigger than the input, and is really good at multiplying.)

`^` anchors the expression to the beginning of each line, making it process each number in the list exactly once, thanks to the `m`ultiline flag. The result of each adds to the total (instead of multiplying the total), since they are independent matches not done in concert.

Non-atomic lookahead, added to PCRE2 in v10.34 as `(*napla:`...`)` and given the `(?*`...`)` synonym in v10.35, makes calculating \$n^k\$, where \$k\$ is a constant, very easy in -regex. `(?*x+){4}` is equivalent to `(?*x+)(?*x+)(?*x+)(?*x+)`. Each `(?*x+)` essentially picks a number in \$[1,n]\$, cycling through all the values effectively independently of the others, so the number of possible choices that lead to a full match is \$n^4\$.

It would not be possible to emulate this kind of solution using lookbehind with recursion to emulate variable-length-lookbehind, because that requires using lookahead nested inside lookbehind, both of which are atomic – so only one possible match would be tried. And even if it were not for that problem, the engine will complain of "nested recursion at the same subject position", which is unavoidable.

## Regex  (PCRE / Raku<sup>`:P5`</sup>), 27 bytes

```
(|xxx|((||){2}||)xx?)x*x*x+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVThbts2EP6vp7h4aExaTGDZbdpaUYMuy7AfWVMYKbAiDQSFpmwhMiVQ0uwk9t89wB5xDzL3SEq23KRxLFPHu@@@@45HnudHU843vySSp9VEwGnOlTiefXD4LFIQ5je3EMC48@ticX83rL4@PPx1PTtZzMiGrJbL5YqQ1Yo@Ddb4XC7P6LKHH3dDf3TvMOjlQZi7nu/sUhXlJMl0rrZJJXK6b0sytIpo/tzvg5PIEnJclqFQKlOEZ7IowXDvzUVRRFNBnzDPaMTRAU5PobbqpbELOUl9UKKslATPXzuVLJKpFBNIMzm1j0gWC6F8k23@EPIoTbOqJFqq5iW8SzN@Dz1O4cm6u@4Wto@wJjZKJEEHB/Avv8EiUiFJTo@826DvgyVkS4OcBx1yNur4uHKD3P50KDk7x@8BRXuFkMNBWEKmgzX@FBcGuw2UyLwqdbgS0FPCh7ZGKEpeKhutRFGlpV1rNeO4ECUDLA5ZTsuZ3cn@FrzM1M3w1qZC1ACsEtk8T1KBshzzEJMTyuDz@fgi/O3q@uPlJazs25fr398xOLSZ7aJJ1acWM4mBHChBG/1i0@KYYFnozaCjgQxHBRFSMuHwajKCV8U3iYethWnz1MDtjiHtXS/tdox4RBf5qBU1Ik5FmSZSEHuGEsmsntRHH69pZcP5kQLuaWVJ95vsWiffbJmo4yJ5FIQGQZ/qLpSJrIS/Q8DEqLRObZtT7Pa2zPKsQAe/nbmJlWIRYjwDiaVFZZbUSetmgKuDqb8fh9S09Qe47RniWigclQ7r@M89MA/RVHsU5xN15KRgQGoeuKmfLnj4lTq9R1/AuEEn19W3TJd19/fXINJCvERtl3hu87aSvphqvfc2F3M8G6RARyNYd9lF1bBdho3GsGiaVXMQGiXkPjCKh05W6DiRE4JVMGM1JBqBIQjaQzkaSaP6Hep271v3AG8f5znf/TbAf//8Czj79oox9Laedn6baRRLwYkSDD59ubxkgI0xpfbNfz3EDIYtnTRVi3Hah8PDBu8gsHN7MR5fjcNPV39@vD7/gzo/PyoXei5bx0U38efudSXNdRynVTF7oaa6zrVjpn5kx1UJgYzp9p6tbzBnvRmwoeO9ZidOnw3eOM5bZ8g8s/QYbrHX7A07YW/ZO/Ze2z2PeYP/eZxG02JzlGr9vgM) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP7vp5i6EplJBjYOhbIxBlGIBFILVRq03VJkGWeSWNhjyx6XQMnffYB9xH2QZc9c7Dgk1QbizJw55zvX@Rxm2fY0DF/ejtkk4gx9Ph0Oev7p1dnAv768GPl/XJyNztGB9TbiYVyOGTrMwpz1dmZHVjgLcuRnN7fIQ0P7w8PD/d1u@efj49fRbP9hhl/w83w@f8b4@Zn87C3gOZ8fk3kb/jov5LW6TVE78/ys47gNX4XIIz6VzpayKAUpC5KjNb0jK@ICZbAUPsvzNMdhyguBVKDthBVFMGUE/SzEuN8PQQMdHiIjlkslZ3wcuyhnosw5ctzFGqbch@mYUXSXpjFKvUkQFxJWuTFwN729/VvXQvCJJgirmvlTZjB8o4U1DtZFvz49PxketIk5pKiInlg6wXXgv1WShj4hRHmRH5yiY51EmJYC9VGdKJHp2coMqQj6yH6VvDK2bbCyv3Ob1PWYxGUx05nURbEWVsmLaMrZGMUpn@pHwIsHlruqYMmjHwZxDGGY3M3Ov4vT8B61Q4p@pNEYtceBCKB2skhyiTwPYXnSJltLDGKwO526M13TmSSIOAYAFWB2A4MQM44zsu3cel1Xp6CnA2WhZ@Pjvu3CquNl@scm@PgUvm8IyEtA3O35ApoKthJ@CgsF3QSKeFYKaa4Sgxaids6qfRKIcOarXNrLtUbLWVHGguoWuOaufbn4NlCSyaRgcAj5QgpTMVtRaKc/WCjAynQC7lzlP8mimGEzFF8@j4YkC3dCH4LFhBqMb4PhlT8aDD9dXJ6MBmeVePB1NLg8k/stFZP5NZF0yXKC3@QwgKb2zdugnkavkbq3Vg0f9oFg/iRPEz8LhGA5xzlM@eX1x48GoGkDV1ewuYAiVitv07mBxWsokEE9ghUEbcwl3TRnrwG0qzhKoibItkPchtKYZeJ/lXIWlnkRpXyjonI7SXOk2OWpnlxgjBhYGeuLHHGqZ4@41cRX7XkiCOSSgXDrO2@B6yfPcdWRstiRzIGJ53UJkp4jXjJ3iQBOYeakW82VxfKsjipLC1BY8VzZcvbggz1FHJoUiDQyTs0Qoo40Ju6qnaRFkL6Cq@@aojDJWtR21zXAD5ahtgm0H3oX4gIaauKAQ/nsIAe@XLp3yAaMG1DqdOTbq0Vbq@cLxIDTN4W2dJxovw2nG10tVnYJS2AacAGKqmCteQuqBu1S0UgMjSajqoagqgRfBYbigZIuNLy6xxiyoEqqgqgKLBm1QV79PldVv4O63bta3ZOUvh7vahvQP3/9jYAjNROr8GpNzWurF1Td7SYpQYNUyl31vyQGWJu70KicDF6jHnbR1pbx8MYztDUcXg39y6tPJ6PTc7JalQY3VXQr8pI1sGVrrV/Om8lvw@tv8SuOAk5jDC@zWOc@rVDvSfPloQ@BXut3m44b3rIvPbprOe/ovtWlvT3Lem/tUkctHQpH9B3do/v0PT2gv0u541Cn9284iYNp8bIdKxfbB/8B) - PCRE2 v10.33 / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbdUttGFL6un2JRZvCuvRDLBEItBEPBMzCTQMYx0zSE0Qh5bWuQVxppFQzBt32A3OamN73ME_RJ0ss-Sc_-SJawOzVI3p9zvvO73_rb9yCJ8kw-3iQIvl9bW1ESpKy7tW_d_Bi8GLFxyBl6dzLod72Ty9O-d3VxPvR-PT8dnqH9xouQB1E-YuhAKW1PDxvB1E-Rl1zfIBcNrF_u7-9ud_LfHh4-DKd791P8Zy7GW_t_4af5fP6E8dMT-dJdwHs-PyLzFvy1tcTfP22S58oWRa3E9ZK27VQsZyIN-USaXq6FMawyf3a4InfYCLlACQyFx9I0TnEQ80wg5XZrxrLMnzCCvmRi1OsFIIEODpBZlkO1zvgoclDKRJ5yZDuLFUw5D-IRo-g2jiMUu2M_yiSsMmPgrru7ezdOA8EnHCOsMuhNmMHwjBTWOFiX4Ork7Hiw3yJmk6IsfGTxGJeOvyxWKvKEEGVFfnCMjnQQQZwL1ENloESGZyk1pDzoIetZ8ErZskDL-sQtUuZjDO0z1ZGUSWksGjnPwglnIxTFfKJfPs_uWeqohM0evMCPInDDxG5m3m0UB3eoFVD0OQ5HqDXyhQ-5k0mSQ-S6CMudFtlcYhCD3W6XlemYysz8kGMAUA4m19AIEeM4IVv2jdtxdAi6O1ASuBY-6lkOjNpuor8sgo9O4NkgsJ4D4k7XE1BU0JXwExgo6CpQyJNcSHUVGJQQtVJWzGe-CKaeiqW1HGu0lGV5JKgugWNO3vvzj321Mh5nDDYhXghhIqY1gVb8mQUCtEwl4AQW9mdJGDFsmuL9u-GAJMF24IGzmFCD8bE_uPSG_cHb84vjYf-0WO5_GPYvTuV8U_lkvo0nHbLs4I0UGtDkvnoa1NvIVUJ3V7LhwdwXzBun8cxLfCFYynEKXX5x9eaNAajqwNEVbC4gicXIXbdvYPEKCkRQtmABQSt9Sdf12XMAbSoKZ2EVZMsmTkVoxBLxv0IpC_I0C2O-VlCZHccpUuzyWHYuMEYEHI31QQ451b1HnKLji_I8EgTrkoFw8xNvgulH13bUltLYlsyBiet2CJKWQ54zZ4kARqHnpFnNldlyr_QqiTMQqFkudDm790CfIg5F8kUcGqOmCVFbKhOnridpEVafwZVnTVGYZC1qOasSYAdLV1sEyg-1C3AGBTV-wKZ8t5END5fmbbIG4xqE2m15lzVps76_QAw4fZ1rS8MzbbdidK2pRW02YzPoBpyBoEpYc96ErEG5lDcSQ6NJr4omKDLB68CQPBDSiYaLfIQhCqpWlRNFgiWjVsir1-Mq67eQtztHi7uS0lf9rZcB_fP7VwQcqZlYuVdKal6rH1B1tqukBAVSIXfU_5IYYGzOQiVz0nmNetBBm5vGwoZraGswuBx4F5dvj4cnZ6SelQo3FXQr0pxVsGVpazq1QE18a66_xX9xFHAaY3gZxSr3aYFyTqqXh94Eei3vNu033LL659IfP3a6dKdhv6J7jQ7t7jYarxs71FZDm8IWfUV36R59Tffpz3Ldtqnd1br_Ag) - PCRE2 v10.40+
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/basJAEH3frxiDNLtxqtlYtTUE2weferFCWyhWxJYEt8SYZhVWkvjYD@gn9kfSiRRaBg7DOTPnzKRhFvernQ7hdnJ3PX72Yb2HkwgCGD9d3cB0lrfWw9AM73udORygGUQqUXpF7XTWKTcHZ@4z2mjqwPUh2mQQqyTUXEAOKiIacr3cg2WVfj0jfQZHftF@Wy0z3QgCF3LioI69jClWp7HachttBL171duMNxcIzqkkEOGH9ZJYMBr901wkUUCjQa7CP3qlmUq2ZNd@36ik9hJ0rw3fn1@EB4g4J229TIdgG9s44m9O0JnO5PGhHcU7vfLLkv0@XPHCGFNwXhQi90pCY0bCOFStqvKwy@QZ9pmLXo@xAeuiPLYSScIz7GEfB3iOFzUvJUrvBw) - Raku (Perl 6)

```
(
                 # apply once with tail = N
|
    xxx          # apply once with tail = N-3
|
    ((||){2}||)  # apply 3**2+2==11 times...
    xx?          # ...with tail = N-1 or N-2
)
x*x*x+           # tail'th pentatope number
```

Although PCRE and Raku are the only regex engines currently capable of counting this regex's number of possible matches without their source code being patched, this regex itself only uses a **POSIX ERE** level of functionality, so is in theory universally compatible with all regex engines.

Lacking non-atomic lookahead, the only golf-efficient way I can think of to cause the number of possible matches to be \$n^k\$, where \$k\$ is a constant, is to decompose \$n^k\$ into a sum of \$n\$-simplex numbers. \$4\$-simplex numbers have the formula \$S_4(n)=n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/24\$. So what we want is to solve is:

$$n^4=a⋅S_4(n)+b⋅S_4(n-1)+c⋅S_4(n-2)+d⋅S_4(n-3)$$

for \$a,b,c,d\$. The general form of this turns out to have the \$k\$th [Euler's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number) row as its solution. In the case of \$n^4\$, this is \$1,11,11,1\$.

The -regex for \$S_4(n)\$ is `x*x*x+`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVX9btpIEP@fp5i4urALpgWqqyKME@UIUiK1SUWJrtcUWY69hlXN2rLXJckp/94D3CPegxw3@wE4AekWMLs7M7/5Hkd53plH0fpNzBIuGHweTcb9YHRzMQ5ur6@mwe9XF9NLOGm84SJKq5jBMI8K1n@7OG1Ei7CAIL@bgQ8T57fV6sf9@@qPx8ev08WH1YKsH1r4aa/pa4rjQiv3g7zd82qwpSy4mCvc3R3P8JaFy9M9vtMGFxJy3MqAFUVWkCgTpQRtU2vJyjKcMwp/ljIeDCLkgOEQ7LXa6nsm4tSDgsmqENDznvcw1TnKYubCfZalkPlJmJYKVquxcHf9Xz/MvAbg4gkQHZ5gzixGYLmIwSEmvrejy/PJSYtaogslf2JZQraGv9vc1PgppVqLWiSDM@NElFUSBrB1lCr3HC0G2oIBOK@c18KOg1LOd@HQbTyStCoXxpNtUBrPjUqUfC5YDGkm5uYRinLFCk8HbPkYRGGaohnWd3sK7tMs@gGtyIWfGY@hFYcyxNipIKkt@D4QRWnR4x0Gtdjt9jYzXZuZZcgFQQBtYH6HhZAyQXLa6c38rmdcMNUBeeQ75GzgeLhr@7n5cyg5G@HviOJ9hYjv@4HEpKKsgp/jRkPXgbjIK6nEtWOYQmgVbHNehjJaBNqX1m5v0ApWVql0TQo821Zfrr6N9U2SlAyJ6C@6MJeLFwyt7CeLJErZTGB7bfQvc54yYoviy@fphObR2yhAYwl1Lca38eQmmI4nn66uz6fji831@Ot0fH2hzsfaJvtvLenSXQUfFViANvb1btBPy1dz3d@LRoDnULIgKbJlkIdSskKQAqv8@vbjRwtQl8HWlexBYhA3O/8Q3cKSPRT0YFuCGwi3VpfuoTp7DWBUpXzJ6yCdHvVqTDHL5f8yFSyqipJn4iCjVptkBejp8rStXJwYKQ5gYhqZC9fUHvU2Fa/TgyKii@EJZcaJZtikH/Mvei7kWYlkQ8GBHpNmp2mVqiV6KrbIc@TX63wwEOry7AAutDV/G3oUB4bo7rDMrFXqBFuZ053otXszD4fNEiNBSheaD01lGAaoROLMr8lvg8B9oXpw6IueB@02r3u8KconCmiUUkKa3wW6hKFDbl2fCXF@ieGfv/4GfLVwJJkRgobVtJleUk35srp0YdY7Co3m2BD6u6tp3Ns0Um/POIM77MLxsdVx5Nuum0xuJsH1zafz6eiSvhDU5Vdrr83EkEXFXulg@NbZk91Nf5zf1uMDk1yt58bueaixkoIxsvNvv6ENw/ZM6xPREHFmbAe28QRfHetup9/9N0rScF6uO6mW6Zz8Bw)

What we need to do is have it match \$1\$ time on \$n\$, \$11\$ times on \$n-1\$, \$11\$ times on \$n-2\$, and \$1\$ time on \$n-3\$.

Multiplying the number of possible matches of a subexpression can be done simply by concatenating, for example, `(|||)` to multiply by \$4\$. As a standalone regex returning \$4(n+1)\$, this can simply be `|||`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP6fpzi4WjKTOG1MtRWKMYgNkUBqoUqDtluKLGOPk1GdsWWPS2Hh7z5AH7EPsuyZixNDIq0Fzsy5fOd@HBfFYB7HT68SlnLB4ON4OtkLxxcnk/Dy/GwW/nl2MjuF/c4rLuKsThgcFHHJ9l4vDjvxIiohLK6uIYCp88ft7bebt/Vfd3efZ4t3twvy9PDw8ERfkh0XekUQFn3Pb2FWsuRirkDXNJ4jlUXLww25ww4XEgo8ypCVZV6SOBeVBO1Qb8mqKpozCn9XMhmNYpSAgwOwZHXUdCaSzIeSyboU4PmPG5jqHucJc@EmzzPIgzTKKgWrzVi4q73f3137HcCHp0B0bsI5sxihlSIGh5jkXo5Pj6f7PWqZLlT8nuUpWTn@pqG05Cml2op6SA5HJog4ryWMYBUoVeE5Wg20ByNwXgSvlR0HtZyvwqGrfKRZXS1MJKukdB47taj4XLAEslzMzSsS1S0rfZ2w5V0YR1mGbtjY7S28yfL4G/RiF77nPIFeEskIc6eSpI4QBEAUp0d31xjUYvf7q8oMbWWWERcEAbSDxRU2QsYEKejAuw6GvgnBdAcUceCQo5Hj46kfFObHoeRojP87FOk1Ir7dCyUWFXUV/BwPGroNxEVRS6WuA8MSQq9kzX0ZyXgR6lh667NBK1lVZ9I1JfDtTH06@zLRlDStGDIxXgxhLhfPBHr5dxZL1LKVwNlq7C8LnjFim@LTx9mUFvHrOERnCXUtxpfJ9CKcTaYfzs6PZ5OThjz5PJucn6j7rvbJ/lpPhnTdwTslNqDNfXsa9NvKtUIPNrIR4j2SLEzLfBkWkZSsFKTELj@/fP/eArR1cHQl@yExic0p2Ma3sGQDBSNYtWAD4bb60t3WZy8BjKmML3kbZOBRvyWUsEL@r1DJ4rqseC62CmqzaV6C3i73q87FjZHh9iVmkLlwTe9Rv@l4XR5UEUNMTyRzTrRAU36sv/BcKPIK2YaD2zwh3UHXGlWP8FRuUWYnaPf5aCQU8WgLLvS1fB88igtDDNdYZtcqc4LdmtuV8PretY/LZomZIJUL3R9d5RgmqELmddDSXyWBB0LN4EEgPB/6fd6OuGnKewrolDJCul8FhoSpQ2ndnylxfkvg1z8/AT8tHFlmhaBjLWtmltRQPu8u3ZjtiUKnOQ6E/lv3NJ5tGam/4ZzBPRjC7q61sRPYqZtOL6bh@cWH49n4lD5T1O3XGq9mY8iyZi9sMPzqbOiutz/ubxvxlk2unsfO@r1tsNKSMbKOb3OgjcDqTtsb0TBxZ6wWtokEPx1Pw4E3HP4bp1k0r54GmVYa7P8H) - note that this is \$4(n+1)\$ because an empty regex returns \$n+1\$ possible matches.

The simplest choice for multiplying by \$11\$ would be `(||||||||||)`, but it turns out this can be optimized down to `((||){2}||)`, as \$11=3^2+2\$, where `(||){2}` is \$3^2\$ and each additional `|` adds \$1\$. Larger numbers can be additionally optimized by factorization. Additionally, there's expressions like `(|){3,5}` for \$56=2^3+2^4+2^5\$.

So, `((||){2}||)xx?` is the part where it's creating \$11\$ possibilities each, `((||){2}||)`,  in which the subsequent expression is evaluated on \$n-1\$ or \$n-2\$, using `xx?`.

The first several n-simplex functions are as follows, in -regex:

\$S_0(n)\$: `^` (returns \$1\$)
\$S_1(n)\$: `x` (returns \$n\$)
\$S_2(n)\$: `x+` (triangular numbers)
\$S_3(n)\$: `x*x+` (tetrahedral numbers)
\$S_4(n)\$: `x*x*x+` (pentatope numbers)
\$S_5(n)\$: `x(x*){4}`
\$S_6(n)\$: `x(x*){5}`

The first several \$n^k\$ are as follows:

\$n^0\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP6fpzi4WjKTON2YaisUYxAbIoHUQpUGbbeUtYw9TkZ1xpY9bgor/vYB@oj7IMueuTgxJNJa4Mycy3fux3FRDOZx/PQqYSkXDD6Mp5ODcHx1NgmvLy9m4R8XZ7NzOOy84iLO6oTBURGX7OD14rgTL6ISwuLmFgKYOr@vVl/v3tR/3t9/mi3erhbk6a8n@pLouNArgrDoe34LsZIlF3MFuaHxHKksWh5vyR13uJBQ4FGGrCzzksS5qCRod3pLVlXRnFH4u5LJaBSjBBwdgSWro6YzkWQ@lEzWpQDPf9zCVPc4T5gLd3meQR6kUVYpWG3Gwt0c/Pb21u8APjwFojMTzpnFCK0UMTjEpPZ6fH46PexRy3Sh4g8sT8na8V8bSkueUqqtqIfkcGKCiPNawgjWgVIVnqPVQHswAudF8FrZcVDL@SIcus5HmtXVwkSyTkrnsVOLis8FSyDLxdy8IlGtWOnrhC3vwzjKMnTDxm5v4V2Wx1@hF7vwLecJ9JJIRpg7lSR1hCAAojg9ur/BoBa7319XZmgrs4y4IAigHSxusBEyJkhBB95tMPRNCKY7oIgDh5yMHB9P/aAwPw4lJ2P836NIrxHxzUEosaioq@DneNDQbSAuiloqdR0YlhB6JWvuy0jGi1DH0tucDVrJqjqTrimBbyfq48XniaakacWQifFiCHO5eCbQy7@xWKKWrQROVmN/WfCMEdsUHz/MprSIX8chOkuoazE@T6ZX4WwyfX9xeTqbnDXkyafZ5PJM3fe1T/bXejKkmw7eK7EBbe7b06DfVq4VerCVjRDvkWRhWubLsIikZKUgJXb55fW7dxagrYOjK9l3iUlsTsEuvoUlWygYwboFGwi31Zfurj57CWBMZXzJ2yADj/otoYQV8n@FShbXZcVzsVNQm03zEvR2eVh3Lm6MDHcvMYPMhWt6j/pNx@vyoIoYYnoimXOiBZryY/2F50KRV8g2HNzlCekOutaoeoSncosye0G7z0cjoYgnO3Chr@X74FFcGGK4wTK7VpkTbGVuN8Lre7c@LpslZoJULnS/d5VjmKAKmbdBS3@dBB4INYNHgfB86Pd5O@KmKR8ooFPKCOl@ERgSpg6ldX@mxPklgX9@/AT8tHBkmRWCjrWsmVlSQ/m8u3RjticKneY4EPpv09N4tmWk/pZzBvdoCPv71sZeYKduOr2ahpdX709n43P6TFG3X2u8mo0hy5q9sMHwq7Olu9n@uL9txDs2uXoeO5v3rsFKS8bIJr7tgTYC6zttb0TDxJ2xXtgmEvx0PA0H3nD4b5xm0bx6GmRaaXD4Hw) `^`
\$n^1\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP6fpzi4WphJnDam2grFGMSGSCC1oUqDtluKLGOPk1GdsWWPy2XF332AfcR9kM2euTgxJNJa4Mycy3fux3FR9OdxvHqTsJQLBp9H0/FhOLo6H4fXk8tZ@Pvl@ewCjjpvuIizOmFwXMQlO3y7OOnEi6iEsLi5hQCmzm/39z/u3td/PD5@nS0@3C/I6mFFXxMdF7pFEBY9z28hVrLkYq4gNzSeI5VFy5MtuZMOFxIKPMqQlWVekjgXlQTtTnfJqiqaMwp/VjIZDmOUgONjsGR11HQmksyHksm6FOD5z1uY6h7nCXPhLs8zyIM0yioFq81YuJvDXz/c@h3Ah6dAdGbCObMYoZUiBoeY1F6PLs6mR11qmS5U/InlKVk7/q6htOQppdqKekgOpyaIOK8lDGEdKFXhOVoNtAdDcF4Fr5UdB7Wc78Kh63ykWV0tTCTrpHSeO7Wo@FywBLJczM0rEtU9K32dsOVjGEdZhm7Y2O0tvMvy@Ad0Yxd@5jyBbhLJCHOnkqSOEARAFKdL9zcY1GL3euvKDGxllhEXBAG0g8UNNkLGBClo37sNBr4JwXQHFHHgkNOh4@OpFxTmx6HkdIT/exTpNSK@PwwlFhV1FfwcDxq6DcRFUUulrgPDEkK3ZM19Gcl4EepYupuzQStZVWfSNSXw7UR9ufw21pQ0rRgyMV4MYS4XLwS6@U8WS9SylcDJauwvC54xYpviy@fZlBbx2zhEZwl1Lca38fQqnI2nny4nZ7PxeUMef52NJ@fqvq99sr/WkwHddPBeiQ1oc9@eBv22cq3Qg61shHiPJAvTMl@GRSQlKwUpscsn1x8/WoC2Do6uZA8Sk9icgl18C0u2UDCCdQs2EG6rL91dffYawJjK@JK3Qfoe9VtCCSvk/wqVLK7Liudip6A2m@Yl6O3ytO5c3BgZ7l5iBpkL1/Qe9ZuO1@VBFTHA9EQy50QLNOXH@gvPhSKvkG04uMsTctA/sEbVIzyVW5TZC9p9PhwKRTzdgQs9Ld8Dj@LCEIMNltm1ypxg9@Z2I7yed@vjslliJkjlwsHDgXIME1Qh8zZo6a@TwAOhZvA4EJ4PvR5vR9w05RMFdEoZIQffBYaEqUNp3Z8pcX5J4J@//gb8tHBkmRWCjrWsmVlSQ/myu3RjticKneY4EPpv09N4tmWk/pZzBvd4APv71sZeYKduOr2ahpOrT2ez0QV9oajbrzVezcaQZc1e2WD41dnS3Wx/3N824h2bXD3Pnc1712ClJWNkE9/2QBuB9Z22N6Jh4s5YL2wTCX46VoO@Nxj8G6dZNK9W/Uwr9Y/@Aw) `x`
\$n^2\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP6fpzi4WjKTOG1MtRWKMYgNkUBqoUqDtluKLGOPk1GdsWWPG2DF332AfcR9kGXPXJwYEmktcGbO5Tv347goBvM4fn6TsJQLBp/H08lBOL46m4TXlxez8PeLs9k5HHbecBFndcLgqIhLdvB2cdyJF1EJYXFzCwFMnd9Wqx937@s/Hh6@zhYfVgvyfH9y33@mr@mOC70iCIu@57dAK1lyMVeoGxrPkcqi5fGW3HGHCwkFHmXIyjIvSZyLSoL2qLdkVRXNGYU/K5mMRjFKwNERWLI6ajoTSeZDyWRdCvD8py1MdY/zhLlwl@cZ5EEaZZWC1WYs3M3Brx9u/Q7gw1MgOjnhnFmM0EoRg0NMdq/H56fTwx61TBcq/sjylKwdf9dQWvKUUm1FPSSHExNEnNcSRrAOlKrwHK0G2oMROK@C18qOg1rOd@HQdT7SrK4WJpJ1UjpPnVpUfC5YAlku5uYViWrFSl8nbPkQxlGWoRs2dnsL77I8/gG92IWfOU@gl0QywtypJKkjBAEQxenR/Q0Gtdj9/royQ1uZZcQFQQDtYHGDjZAxQQo68G6DoW9CMN0BRRw45GTk@HjqB4X5cSg5GeP/HkV6jYjvD0KJRUVdBT/Hg4ZuA3FR1FKp68CwhNArWXNfRjJehDqW3uZs0EpW1Zl0TQl8O1RfLr5NNCVNK4ZMjBdDmMvFC4Fe/pPFErVsJXC4GvvLgmeM2Kb48nk2pUX8Ng7RWUJdi/FtMr0KZ5Ppp4vL09nkrCFPvs4ml2fqvq99sr/WkyHddPBeiQ1oc9@eBv22cq3Qg61shHiPJAvTMl@GRSQlKwUpscsvrz9@tABtHRxdye4lJrE5Bbv4FpZsoWAE6xZsINxWX7q7@uw1gDGV8SVvgww86reEElbI/xUqWVyXFc/FTkFtNs1L0Nvlcd25uDEyXL/EDDIXruk96jcdr8uDKmKI6YlkzokWaMqP9ReeC0VeIdtwcJ0npDvoWqPqEZ7KLcrsBe0@H42EIp7swIW@lu@DR3FhiOEGy@xaZU6wlbndCK/v3fq4bJaYCVK50L3vKscwQRUyb4OW/joJPBBqBo8C4fnQ7/N2xE1TPlJAp5QR0v0uMCRMHUrr/kyJ80sC//z1N@CnhSPLrBB0rGXNzJIaypfdpRuzPVHoNMeB0H@bnsazLSP1t5wzuEdD2N@3NvYCO3XT6dU0vLz6dDobn9MXirr9WuPVbAxZ1uyVDYZfnS3dzfbH/W0j3rHJ1fPU2bx3DVZaMkY28W0PtBFY32l7Ixom7oz1wjaR4KfjeTjwhsN/4zSL5tXzINNKg8P/AA) `x?x+` (squares)
\$n^3\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP6fpzi4WphJnDam2grFGMSGSCC1UKVB2y1FlrHHyajO2LLHJbDh7z7APuI@yGbPXJIYEmktcOZyzndu3zmOi6I7iePlm4SlXDD4PBgND8PB9fkwvLm6HIe/X56PL@Co9YaLOKsTBsdFXLLDt9OTVjyNSgiL2zsIYOT89vDw4/59/cfj49fx9MPDlCzJYj5fkMViQed03p53lvS1jONCuwjCouP5DQOVLLmYKAubM57jKYtmJ1tyJy0uJBS4lCEry7wkcS4qCdq79oxVVTRhFP6sZNLvxygBx8dgj9VSnzORZD6UTNalAM9/3sJU@zhPmAv3eZ5BHqRRVilYbcbC3R7@@uHObwE@PAWiExVOmMUIrRQxOMRk@mZwcTY6alN76ULFn1iekrXj71YnDXlKqbaiHpLDqQkizmsJfVgHSlV4jlYD7UEfnFfBa2XHQS3nu3DoOh9pVldTE8k6Ka3nVi0qPhEsgSwXE/OKRPXASl8nbPYYxlGWoRs2drsL77M8/gHt2IWfOU@gnUQywtypJKklBAEQddOm@xsMarE7nXVlerYys4gLggDaweIWiZAxQQra9e6Cnm9CMOyAIg4cctp3fFx1gsL8OJScDvB/j@J5jYjvD0OJRUVdBT/BhYZuAnFR1FKp68CwhNAu2Wo/i2Q8DXUs7c3aoJWsqjPpmhL4tsG@XH4b6pM0rRheYrwYwkROXwi0858slqhlK4GNtrI/K3jGiCXFl8/jES3it3GIzhLqWoxvw9F1OB6OPl1enY2H56vj4dfx8Opc7fe1T/bXetKjGwbvlUhAm/tmN@i3lWuEHmxlI8R9JFmYlvksLCIpWSlIiSy/uvn40QI0dbB1JZtLTOJqFey6t7BkCwUjWFNwBeE2eOnu4tlrAGMq4zPeBOl61G8IJayQ/ytUsrguK56LnYLabJqXoKfL05q5ODEyHMXENDIXruEe9VeM1@VBFdHD9EQy50QLrMqP9ReeC0Ve4bW5wdGekIPugTWqHuGp3KLMXtDkeb8v1OHpDlzoaPkOeBQHhuhtsMysVeYEezC7W@F1vDsfh80MM0EqFw7mB8oxTFCFl3dBQ3@dBB4I1YPHgfB86HR4M@IVKZ8ooFPKCDn4LjAkTB1Ka36mxPklgX/@@hvw08LxyowQdKxhzfSSasqX7NLEbHYUOs2xIfTfhtO4tmWk/pZzBve4B/v71sZeYLtuNLoehVfXn87Ggwv6QlHTr9Feq4khy5q9ssHwq7Olu5n@OL9txDsmuXqeW5v3rsZKS8bIJr7thjYC6z1tTkRziTNjPbBNJPjpWPa6Xu/fOM2iSbXsZlqne/Qf) `(|xx|(|||)x)x*x+` (cubes)
\$n^4\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP6fpzi4WphJnG5MtRWKMYgNkUBqQ5UGbbcUWcYeJ6M6Y8sel0Dh7z7APuI@yGbPXJIYEmkNceZyzndu3zmJi6I7jePlm4SlXDD4NBgPD8PB1fkwvB5dTsI/Ls8nF3DUesNFnNUJg@MiLtnh29lJK55FJYTFzS0EMHZ@v7//fveu/vPh4ctk9v5@RpbkabFYPBHy9ER/Hj7je7E4pYs2/nWW9LW440K7CMKi4/kNW5UsuZgqY5sznuMpi@YnW3InLS4kFLiUISvLvCRxLioJ2tH2nFVVNGUUflYy6fdjlIDjY7DHaqnPmUgyH0om61KA5z9vYap9nCfMhbs8zyAP0iirFKw2Y@FuDn97f@u3AB@eAtE5C6fMYoRWihgcYpJ@Pbg4Gx@1qb10oeKPLE/J2vFfVycNeUqptqIeksOpCSLOawl9WAdKVXiOVgPtQR@cV8FrZcdBLeebcOg6H2lWVzMTyTopredWLSo@FSyBLBdT84pEdc9KXyds/hDGUZahGzZ2uwvvsjz@Du3YhR85T6CdRDLC3KkkqSUEARB106b7GwxqsTuddWV6tjLziAuCANrB4gaJkDFBCtr1boOeb0Iw7IAiDhxy2nd8XHWCwnw5lJwO8LNH8bxGxHeHocSioq6Cn@JCQzeBuChqqdR1YFhCaJdstZ9HMp6FOpb2Zm3QSlbVmXRNCXzba58vvw71SZpWDC8xXgxhKmcvBNr5DxZL1LKVwJ5b2Z8XPGPEkuLzp8mYFvHbOERnCXUtxtfh@CqcDMcfL0dnk@H56nj4ZTIcnav9vvbJfltPenTD4L0SCWhz3@wG/bZyjdCDrWyEuI8kC9Myn4dFJCUrBSmR5aPrDx8sQFMHW1eyhcQkrlbBrnsLS7ZQMII1BVcQboOX7i6evQYwpjI@502Qrkf9hlDCCvm/QiWL67LiudgpqM2meQl6ujyumYsTI8OpTEwjc@Ea7lF/xXhdHlQRPUxPJHNOtMCq/Fh/4blQ5BVemxuc8gk56B5Yo@oRnsotyuwFTZ73@0Idnu7AhY6W74BHcWCI3gbLzFplTrB7s7sRXse79XHYzDETpHLhYHGgHMMEVXh5GzT010nggVA9eBwIz4dOhzcjXpHykQI6pYyQg28CQ8LUobTmZ0qcXxL456@/AX9aOF6ZEYKONayZXlJN@ZJdmpjNjkKnOTaE/t9wGte2jNTfcs7gHvdgf9/a2Ats143HV@NwdPXxbDK4oC8UNf0a7bWaGLKs2SsbDH91tnQ30x/nt414xyRXz3Nr897VWGnJGNnEt93QRmC9p82JaC5xZqwHtokEfzqWva7X@zdOs2haLbuZ1uke/Qc) `(|xxx|((||){2}||)xx?)x*x*x+`
\$n^5\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVX9TttIEP8/TzG4OthNnF5M7xCKMYhCJJBaqNKg65Uiy9jrZFVnbdnrEj7y7z1AH7EPctzsRxJDIt0qsXdnZ37zPY6LojuO4@c3CUu5YPDpZDjYDU8uTwfh1cX5KPzr/HR0BvutN1zEWZ0wOCjiku2@nRy24klUQlhc30AAQ@f93d3323f13/f3X0aTvbsJeZ6Rp9njH/OnGSFPuOjj7vyJIm1Gn5BCH/fmSMQTmbUp8j3T1xCOC@0iCIuO5zf0V7LkYqwMWNF4jlQWTQ/X@A5bXEgocCtDVpZ5SeJcVBK08e0pq6pozCg8VjLp92PkgIMDsGS11XQmksyHksm6FOD58zVMdY7zhLlwm@cZ5EEaZZWC1Wos3PXun3s3fgtw8RSIjmM4ZhYjtFzE4BCTiKuTs@PhfpvaSxcq/sDylCwN/31BafBTSrUWtUgOR8aJOK8l9GHpKFXuOVoMtAV9cF45r4UdB6Wcb8Khy3ikWV1NjCfLoLTmrVpUfCxYAlkuxuYRieqOlb4O2PQ@jKMsQzOs7/YU3mZ5/B3asQs/cp5AO4lkhLFTQVJbCAIg6qZNt1cY1GJ3OsvM9GxmphEXBAG0gcU1FkLGBClo17sJer5xwVQHFHHgkKO@4@OuExTm5VBydIL/LYr0GhHf7YYSk4qyCn6MGw3dBOKiqKUS145hCqFdssV5Gsl4Empf2qu9QStZVWfSNSnwbf99Pv860JQ0rRheor/owlhOXjC08x8slihlM4F9uNA/LXjGiC2Kz59GQ1rEb@MQjSXUtRhfB8PLcDQYfjy/OB4NThfkwZfR4OJUnbe1TfZtLenRVQVvlViANvbNbtBPy9dwPViLRojnSLIwLfNpWERSslKQEqv84urDBwvQlMHWlWwmMYiLXbDp3sKSNRT0YFmCCwi3UZfupjp7DWBUZXzKmyBdj/oNpoQV8n@ZShbXZcVzsZFRq03zEvR0eVhWLk6MDCc1MY3MhWtqj/qLitfpQRHRw/BEMudEMyzSj/kXngtFXuG1ucHJn5Cd7o5VqpbwVGyRZyto1nm/LxTxaAMudDR/BzyKA0P0Vlhm1ip1gt2Z07XwOt6Nj8NmipEglQs7sx1lGAaowsuboCG/DAIPhOrBg0B4PnQ6vOnxoigfKKBRSgnZ@SbQJQwdcuv6TInzWwK//vkJ@GnheGVGCBrW0GZ6STXly@rShdnsKDSaY0Po36qmcW/TSP014wzuQQ@2t62OrcB23XB4OQwvLj8ej07O6AtBXX6N9lpMDFnW7JUOhl@dNdnV9Mf5bT3eMMnVmrdWz02NlZaMkZV/6w1tGJZn2pyI5hJnxnJgG0/w0/Hc63q9f@M0i8bVczfTMt39/wA) `x(|x{4}|x((||||){2}|)(|xx)|((|){6}||)xx)(x*){4}`
\$n^6\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVX9TttIEP8/TzG4OthNnDYGtUIxBnEhEkgtVGnQtaXIMvY6WdVZW/a6hK9/7wHuEe9Bjpv9SGJIpK4Se3d25jff47goupM4fn6TsJQLBp8Ho@FuOLg4GYaX52fj8K@zk/Ep7LfecBFndcLgoIhLtvt2etiKp1EJYXF1DQGMnD9vb3/e7NXf7u6@jqcfbqfkeU4e5w/vnx7nhDzShz0XtxRJ8zl9RAIScdGHXXcP6Ug9omTepijwTF9jOS60iyAsOp7fMKSSJRcTZcmKxnOksmh2uMZ32OJCQoFbGbKyzEsS56KSoL1oz1hVRRNG4aGSSb8fIwccHIAlq62mM5FkPpRM1qUAz39aw1TnOE@YCzd5nkEepFFWKVitxsJd7b7/cO23ABdPgeiAhhNmMULLRQwOMRm5HJwej/bb1F66UPF7lqdkafi7BaXBTynVWtQiORwZJ@K8ltCHpaNUuedoMdAW9MF55bwWdhyUcn4Ihy7jkWZ1NTWeLIPSemrVouITwRLIcjExj0hUt6z0dcBmd2EcZRmaYX23p/Amy@Of0I5d@JXzBNpJJCOMnQqS2kIQAFE3bbq9wqAWu9NZZqZnMzOLuCAIoA0srrAQMiZIQbveddDzjQumOqCIA4cc9R0fd52gMC@HkqMB/rco0mtE3NsNJSYVZRX8BDcaugnERVFLJa4dwxRCu2SL8yyS8TTUvrRXe4NWsqrOpGtS4NtG/HL2fagpaVoxvER/0YWJnL5gaOe/WCxRymYCG3Khf1bwjBFbFF8@j0e0iN/GIRpLqGsxvg9HF@F4OPp0dn48Hp4syMOv4@H5iTpva5vs21rSo6sK3iqxAG3sm92gn5av4XqwFo0Qz5FkYVrms7CIpGSlICVW@fnlx48WoCmDrSvZXGIQF7tg072FJWso6MGyBBcQbqMu3U119hrAqMr4jDdBuh71G0wJK@RvmUoW12XFc7GRUatN8xL0dLlfVi5OjAxHNjGNzIVrao/6i4rX6UER0cPwRDLnRDMs0o/5F54LRV7htbnBT0BCdro7VqlawlOxRZ6toFnn/b5QxKMNuNDR/B3wKA4M0VthmVmr1Al2a05Xwut41z4OmxlGglQu7Mx3lGEYoAovr4OG/DIIPBCqBw8C4fnQ6fCmx4uivKeARiklZOeHQJcwdMit6zMlzh8J/Pv3P4CfFo5XZoSgYQ1tppdUU76sLl2YzY5Cozk2hP6tahr3No3UXzPO4B70YHvb6tgKbNeNRhej8Pzi0/F4cEpfCOrya7TXYmLIsmavdDD86qzJrqY/zm/r8YZJrtZTa/Xc1FhpyRhZ@bfe0IZheabNiWgucWYsB7bxBD8dz72u1/svTrNoUj13My3T3f8f) `x(|x{5}|x((|){3,5}|)(|xxx)|(|)((||||){2,3}|)xxx?)(x*){5}`
\$n^7\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVX9TttIEP8/TzG4OthNnF4MPYRiDOIgEkgtVGnQ9UqRZex1sqqztux1CR/59x7gHvEe5LjZjySGRLpVYu/uzPzmexwXRXccxy/vEpZyweDz6XCwG55enQ3C68uLUfjHxdnoHA5a77iIszphcFjEJdt9PzlqxZOohLC4uYUAhs7v9/c/7vbqPx8evo4m@/cT8jIjz7On/fkzvunTnrs/V@cPc/o8w5tnSvChFn3adffmZktmM3qMdC3yYW5YLANFapsi4At9q8txoV0EYdHx/IahlSy5GCtLV3c8x1sWTY/W@I5aXEgocCtDVpZ5SeJcVBK0l@0pq6pozCg8VTLp92PkgMNDsNdqq@@ZSDIfSibrUoDnz9cw1TnOE@bCXZ5nkAdplFUKVquxcDe7v@3f@i3AxVMgOuDhmFmM0HIRg0NMxq5Pz0@GB21qiS5U/JHlKVka/uvipsFPKdVa1CI5HBsn4ryW0Ielo1S552gx0Bb0wXnjvBZ2HJRyvguHLuORZnU1MZ4sg9Kat2pR8bFgCWS5GJtHJKp7Vvo6YNOHMI6yDM2wvttTeJfl8Q9oxy78zHkC7SSSEcZOBUltIQiAKEqbbq8wqMXudJaZ6dnMTCMuCAJoA4sbLISMCVLQrncb9HzjgqkOKOLAIcd9x8ddJyjMy6Hk@BT/WxTva0Tc2w0lJhVlFfwYNxq6CcRFUUslrh3DFEK7ZIvzNJLxJNS@tFd7g1ayqs6ka1Lg20b9cvFtoG/StGJIRH/RhbGcvGJo5z9ZLFHKZgIbdqF/WvCMEVsUXz6PhrSI38chGkuoazG@DYZX4Wgw/HRxeTIanC2uB19Hg8szdd7WNtm3taRHVxW8VWIB2tg3u0E/LV/D9WAtGiGeI8nCtMynYRFJyUpBSqzyy@uPHy1AUwZbV7KZxCAudsEmuoUlayjowbIEFxBuoy7dTXX2FsCoyviUN0G6HvUbTAkr5P8ylSyuy4rnYiOjVpvmJejp8risXJwYGY50YhqZC9fUHvUXFa/TgyKih@GJZM6JZlikH/MvPBeKvEKyoeAnIiE73R2rVC3hqdgiz1bQrPN@X6jL4w240NH8HfAoDgzRW2GZWavUCXZvTjfC63i3Pg6bKUaCVC7szHaUYRigCom3QUN@GQQeCNWDh4HwfOh0eNPjRVE@UkCjlBKy812gSxg65Nb1mRLnlwT@@etvwE8LR5IZIWhYQ5vpJdWUr6tLF2azo9Bojg2hf6uaxr1NI/XXjDO4hz3Y3rY6tgLbdcPh1TC8vPp0Mjo9p68Edfk12msxMWRZszc6GH511mRX0x/nt/V4wyRXa95aPTc1VloyRlb@rTe0YVieaXMiGiLOjOXANp7gp@Ol1/V6/8ZpFo2rl26mZboH/wE) `x(|x{6}|x(|){3,6}(|x{4})|xx(||)((||||||){2,3}|||||)(xx)?|xxx(|){4}((||||){2,3}|))(x*){6}`
\$n^8\$: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTttIFP6fpzi4WjKTON2YLl0UYxCFSCC1UKVB2y1FlrHHiVVnbNnjYiD5uw@wj7gPsuyZSxJDIq0Fzsy5fOd@HOZ5bxKGz28iFiecwefT0XDPP706G/rXlxdj/4@Ls/E5HLTeJDxMq4jBYR4WbO/t9KgVToMC/PzmFjwYWR/u73/cvav@fHj4Op6@v5@S55rM66ffF/OakPmcPu0v5vhQSdxf0HldK@pvC@Tij63Zil/Xkl0rxoHm70k@lfz6mJK6QxH4mb62adnQyT0/7zpuw@FSFAmfSI/XtCRDKgtmRxtyR62EC8jxKHxWFFlBwoyXAlS0nRkry2DCKDyVIhoMQpSAw0MwZHlUdMaj1IWCiarg4LiLDUx5D7OI2XCXZSlkXhykpYRVZgzczd7@@1u3BfgkMRCVeH/CDIZvpIjGIbpy16fnJ6ODDjVMG8rkkWUxWTn@65LSkKeUKivyIRkc6yDCrBIwgFWgVIZnKTVQHgzAehW8UrYs1LK@c4uu8hGnVTnVkayS0lq0Kl4mE84iSDM@0a@Al/escFXCZg9@GKQpumFiNzf/Ls3CH9AJbfiZJRF0okAEmDuZJHkEzwMiOR26u8agBrvbXVWmbyozCxJOEEA5mN9gI6SMk5z2nFuv7@oQdHdAHnoWOR5YLp66Xq5/LEqOT/F/hyK9QsR3e77AoqKuhJ/gQUE3gRKeV0Kqq8CwhNAp2PI@C0Q49VUsnfVZoxWsrFJh6xK4ZmC/XHwbKkoclwyZGC@GMBHTFwKd7CcLBWqZSuDgLu3P8iRlxDTFl8/jEc3Dt6GPzhJqG4xvw9GVPx6OPl1cnoyHZ0vy8Ot4eHkm77vKJ/NrPOnTdQfvFNiAJvfNaVBvI9cI3dvIho/3QDA/LrKZnwdCsIKTArv88vrjRwPQ1MHRFawWmMTlydvGN7BkAwUjWLXgEsJu9KW9rc9eA2hTaTJLmiA9h7oNoYjl4n@FChZWRZlkfKugMhtnBajt8rjqXNwYKa52ogc54bbuPeouO16VB1V4H9MTiCwhSmBZfqw/d2zIsxLZmoOfioi0e21jVD7ckblFmR2v2eeDAZfE4y240FXyXXAoLgzeX2PpXSvNcXavbzfc6Tq3Li6bGWaClDa067Z0DBNUIvPWa@ivkpB4XM7goccdF7rdpBnxsikfKaBT0ghpf@cYEqYOpVV/xsT6JYJ//vob8NOSIEuvEHSsYU3PkhzKl92lGrM5Ueh0ggOh/tY9jWdTRupuOKdxD/uwu2ts7Hhm6kajq5F/efXpZHx6Tl8oqvZrjNdyY4iiYq9sMPzqbOiutz/ubxPxlk0un0Vr/d42WHHBGFnHtznQWmB1p82NqJm4M1YLW0eCn47nfs/p/xvGaTApn3up0ukd/Ac) `x(|x{7}|x((||){5}||||)(|x{5})|xx(||){4}((|){4,5}|||||)(|xxx)|xxx((|){8}((|){2,5}|)|||)x?)(x*){7}`

Perl 5 severely undercounts the number of possible matches ([Attempt This Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU-9asMwEKZrtr6BECJItZ3YnkpkxQmka6dubRCpiUGgJq7sgIqsjn2Arl0ypE-RN-nYJ-nZDpSD-_nuu7vvvk7V1ujjz9X1yxsihiOn98VGIzLlUIpstXxYzv2o3BtKahHzbM6ZQ6qEirnKqF2D8NMOc48WWtSVVg3FEQ7rw3PdwIgMoyRM2Pa1I-X_aAw4mxHJeLerhosbs9BZytxCPyZrAT5ecz9CqL-sLgBRmegJkAUBc6QASYhiiy1RTLxPaT4jhtE8d0FAijD2rPujHo97qb1SeCPhaJBO1ASj349PhCekAGILLe-lvLtfSfl9aMro9kxba21Ladsyl3rw1ubM3oAFA-N4Cac4SuMh_wM)); see below for a workaround. But Raku's Perl 5 compatibility mode (`:P5` adverb) fully evaluates every choice path (and not just due to its `:ex`haustive adverb – it does the same without it).

## Regex  (Perl <sub><sup>/ PCRE / Raku<sup>`:P5`</sup></sup></sub>), 30 bytes

```
(|xxx|(()||||||||||)xx?)x*x*x+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BbsIwEEX3PoVleWE3U4gDgRYTAhLddtUlkgURSKlMkiap5Cpxlz1Aj9iLpAOVqL3xvD9/5rs61jYezh@U15p2tsz2lvKxxjJZbjcvm5Unp7IWvElCvVxp2dH8hJXsqjovWsp2BdMeVYUWmzTvh6bFbgP3CpQ8vl309J@GyOWCG41TqOAWx63RVdm8FQwYINGEUp7hNvpa5sWVnvdVxxxz3Pi1lcnnWKQLXkuRpl0Q8AxCLzHxX6CbCTtHjP58fVM24hmm6zEj8d6Yp@etMYPonXO9ELK/HelcKt0d3mAYIpgQNYUZCSGKCZmTCajrUwFKMIUYZjCHB3i8cIXfjX4B) - Perl v5.28.2 / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RVA9bsIwFN59CsvyYDcPiBP-igkBia6dOlayaESkVAbSECRXSTr2AF27MLTX6D1Ye4SeoA-oqN9gv-_n-dN7_8iXhd0fflbPlBeaVnaTLCzlHY1tNJ7P7maThqSbQvBt5OvxRMuKZil2ssqLbF1Sdr9mukFWocVG293DtkS1gZYCJZdPRz7-R33E5YgbjVOo4BbHTdGV26wUDBggogmlPMHf6OMmW5_Q1SKvmGOOm2ZqZfTSEfGIF1LEceV5PAG_kZj4HOhiQmWb0e_XN8raPMF0NWYkTWPMze3cmM9dmbaGX6J2ztVCyPpypHOxdFdY3lm0_7sOYQAhUV3oEx-CHiEDEoI6PRUgBV3oQR8GMITrI65wBcHZ-ws) - Perl v5.36+
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVTbbts4EH3XV0xcNCYtJrDiNu1aUYNuNos@ZJvCSIEu0kBQaEoWIlMCJa2dNH7tB@wn7oesOyQlW25SX6nhzJkzZzjkRXGQcL5@kUqe1VMBJwVX4nD2zuGzSEFYXN9AAJPe74vF3e2o/vv@/svV7HgxI2vyuFwuHwmhj5sXXS5P6XKAb3dNf47oMRgUQVi4nu9ss5XVNM11uq5JpTLZtaU5WkU0f@r3zkllBQUuq1AolSvCc1lWYOgP5qIso0TQb5hnPOboACcn0Fj10tiFnGY@KFHVSoLnr5xalmkixRSyXCb2J5LlQijfZJvfhzzKsryuiFarfQhvs5zfwYBT@GbdXXcDO0RYExulkqCDA/gqrrGITEhS0APvJhj6YAnZ0qDgQY@cjns@rtygsH89Sk7P8LtH0V4j5OgorCDXwRo/wYXB7gKlsqgrHa4EDJTwoasRilJUykYrUdZZZddazTguRcUAi0OWSTWzO/k/gle5uh7d2FSIGoBVIp8XaSZQlkMeYnJCGXw6m5yHf1xevb@4gEf79Pnqz7cM9m1mu2hTDanFTGMge0rQVr/YtDgmWBZ6M@hpIMNRQYSUTDi8nI7hZflV4mHrYNo8DXC3Y0h720u7HSMe0UU@aEWNiImoslQKYs9QKpnVk/ro47WtbDk/UMA9rSzpf5V96@SbLRN1WKYPgtAgGFLdhSqVtfC3CJgYldapbXPK7d6GWZGX6OB3M7exUixCjGcgsbSoytMmadMMcHUw9XfjkJq2/gS3OUNcC4Wj0mM9/6kH5iGa6oDifKKOnJQMSMMDN/WvCx5@pU7v0WcwrtHJdfVF02f93f0ViKwUz1HbJp7bvJ2kz6Za7TzNxRzPBinR0QjWX/ZRNWyXYaMxLJpm1R6EVgm5C4zioZMVOk7llGAVzFgNiVZgCILuUI7H0qh@i7rd@dY9wNvHecp3tw3w3/d/AWffXjGG3sbTzm87jWIpOFGCwcfPFxcMsDGm1KH5NEPMYNTRSVO1GCdD2N9v8fYCO7fnk8nlJPx4@df7q7MP1Pn1UTnXc9k5LrqJv3ZvKmmv4ziry9kzNTV1rhwz9WM7rkoIZEw392xzgzmr9REbOd4rduwM2dFrx3njjJhnlh7DLfaKvWbH7A17y37Tds9j3tH/PM6ipFwfZFq/Hw) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrTuNGFP7vpxi8Esw4A43DwtIYg2iIRCQIq2xQt8siyziTxMIeW74sgcLfPkAfsQ9SeuZixyFZNRBn5sw537nO5yBNd2dB8PZhwqYhZ@hzb9TveL3r8753MxyMvd8H5@MLdGR8CHkQlROGjtMgY529@YkRzP0MeentHXLRyPzt8fHhfr/84@np63h@@DjHb/hlsVi8YExe6g9ZLE7JwoK/1ht5b2FSZKWul7Zsp@EuL7KQz4S/pSxMQMr8@GRN78QIeYFSWBYey7Ikw0HC8wLJWK2Y5bk/YwT9mReTbjcADXR8jLRYLKWc8UnkoIwVZcaR7byuYYp9kEwYRfdJEqHEnfpRLmClGw132zk4vHMMBJ9wirAsmzdjGsPTWljhYFX3m97F2ejIIvqQojx8ZskU14H/Ukka@oQQ6UV8cIJOVRJBUhaoi@pEiUjPlGZIRtBF5rvkpbFpgpX5nZukrsc0KvO5yqQuivFqlDwPZ5xNUJTwmXr4PH9kmSMLFj95gR9FEIbOXe@8@ygJHpAVUPQjCSfImviFD7UTRRJL5LoIixOLbC8xiMZuterOtHVnYj/kGABkgOktDELEOE7Jrn3nth2VgpoOlAauiU@7pgOrlpuqH5Pg0x58twjIS0Dc73gFNBVsBfwMFhK6CRTytCyEuUwMWoisjFX72C@CuSdzsZZrhZaxvIwKqlrg6Ov2ZfCtLyXTac7gEPKFFGbFfEXBSn6woAAr3Qm4dpX/OA0jhvVQfPk8HpE02As8CBYTqjG@9UfX3rg/uhoMz8b980rc/zruD8/75@hFC65uLseDy8GwT9G2jFL/6tjaZDnTWxmMpO5G837Ip9ZrFMNdq48He79g3jRLYi/1i4JlHGcw98Oby0sN0LSBy1ywRQFlrVbupnMNi9dQIIN6KCsI2phUumny3gMoV1EYh02QXZs4DaUJS4v/VcpYUGZ5mPCNitLtNMmQ5JvnepaBQyKgaqyudsipmkbiVHegas8zQSAXnIR3vvMdcP3s2o48khZ7gkswcd02QcJzyEvmLBHAKUyhcKvYM1@e1VGlSQ4KK54rW84ePbCniEOT/CIJtVM9lqgljImzaieIEqTv4OrbJ0lN8Bg1nXUN8INFqBaB9kPvApxDQ3UccCieLWTDlwv3NtmAcQtKrZZ4pYmSrSq8IgY0vym2pedYOW543ejrdWUXsxjGAeegKCu2s9iBskG/ZDgCQ6GJsKopqErBV4GheqCkKg0v9AneoYAlpDKIqsKCZBt81u1yWfZ7KNyDo9RdwfLr8a72Af3z198IaFORswyv1lRUt3pD5eVu8hR0SKbclv9LZoC1vgyNyongFepxG21vaw9brmay0eh65A2vr87GvQuyWpUGOVUMXGQla2CL1ho/HTid34Y34uvPSApIjTG8zGKd/JRCvSfN94k6BH6tX3cqbnjxvnXovmF/pIdGm3YODOOTsU9tubQpHNGP9IAe0k/0iP4q5LZN7c6/wTTyZ/nbbiRd7B79Bw) - PCRE2 v10.33 / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbdTuNGFL6un2LwSmTGGWgcFpbGGEQhEki7sMoGdbsssowzSSycsWWPl0Dhtg_Q2970ppf7Cn2P7WWfpGd-7DgkVQN25uec7_zON_n9a5QlZSGfYBJFX6_trSSLctbd2rdvvg1ejdg45gy9Pxn0u8HJ5Wk_uLo4HwY_nZ8Oz9C-9SrmUVKOGDpQStvTQyuahjkKsusb5KOB_eP9_d3tTvnzw8PH4XTvfor_LMV4a_8v_DSfz58wJk_1h8znR2TuwF9bC_393SZ5qW9T5GR-kLVdr2G8EHnMJ9L6Yi1OYZWFs8MVuUMr5gJlMBQBy_M0x1HKC4GU586MFUU4YQT9UohRrxeBBDo4QGZZDtU646PEQzkTZc6R6z2vYMp5lI4YRbdpmqDUH4dJIWGVGQN33d3du_EsBJ94jLBKYjBhBiMwUljjYF2Fq5Oz48G-Q8wmRUX8yNIxrh3_vlppyBNClBX5wSk60kFEaSlQD9WBEhmerdSQ8qCH7BfBK2XbBi37M7dJnY8xdNBUR1InxXq2Sl7EE85GKEn5RL9CXtyz3FMJmz0EUZgk4IaJ3cyC2ySN7pATUfQljUfIGYUihNzJJMkh8n2E5Y5DNhcYxGC323VlOqYyszDmGACUg9k1NELCOM7Ilnvjdzwdgu4OlEW-jY96tgejtp_pL5vgoxN4Ngisl4C40w0EFBV0JfwEBgq6CRTzrBRSXQUGJUROzqr5LBTRNFCxOIuxRstZUSaC6hJ45vB9OP_UVyvjccFgE-KFECZiuiTgpF9YJEDLVAIOYWV_lsUJw6YpPrwfDkgWbUcBOIsJNRif-oPLYNgfvDu_OB72T6vl_sdh_-JUzjeVT-bbeNIhiw7eyKEBTe6bp0G9jVwjdH8lGwHMQ8GCcZ7OgiwUguUc59DlF1dv3xqApg4cXcHmApJYjfx1-wYWr6BABHULVhC00Zd0XZ-9BNCmkngWN0G2XOI1hEYsE_8rlLOozIs45WsFldlxmiPFLo915wJjJEDTWB_kmFPde8SrOr4qzyNBsC4ZCLc-8xaYfvRdT20pjW3JHJj4focgaTnmJfMWCGAUek6a1VxZLPZqr7K0AIEly5UuZ_cB6FPEoUihSGNj1DQhaktl4i3rSVqE1Rdw9VlTFCZZi9reqgTYwdJVh0D5oXYRLqCgxg_YlO82cuHh0rxL1mBcg1C7La-zFm0t7z8jBpy-zrWF4Zm22zC61tTz0mzGZtANuABBlbDWvAVZg3IpbySGRpNeVU1QZYIvA0PyQEgnGu7yEYYoqFpVTlQJlozaIK9ej6us30Le7jwt7ktKX_V3uQzon19_Q8CRmomVe7Wk5rXlA6rOdpOUoEAq5I76XxADjM1ZaGROOq9RDzpoc9NY2PANbQ0Gl4Pg4vLd8fDkjCxnpcFNFd2KvGQNbFnaJZ2lQE18a66_5__iKOA0xvAiilXu0wL1nDQvD70J9FrfbdpvuGX1z6U_vu106Y7lvqZ7Vod2dy3rjbVDXTV0KWzR13SX7tE3dJ_-INddl7pdrfsv) - PCRE2 v10.40+
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/bSsNAEH3fr5iGYnbTsc32qg2h@tAnL7WggtRSqiR0JU1jNoUtafroB/iJ/kicFFFnYDicM3NmJgnSqF9udQA3k9ur8ZMH6x2chODD@PHyGqazvLEeBmZ412vN4QB1P1Sx0iuC01mr2Bycucdooq5914Nwk0Kk4kBzATmokGjI9XIHllV4VY/0GBz5RfN1tUx1zfddyImDau1FRGt1EqmM22gj6O2LzlJeXyA4p5KKCN6t59iC0eif5iKJAmo1chXe0StJVZyRXfNto@LKS9C9Nnx9fFI9QMg5aetlMgTb2MYRf32CznQmD/fNMNrqlVcU7Ofhku@NMXvOxf43hDEjYRzKRlm2scNkF/vMxXaPsQHroDxCiSRhF3vYxwGe4XnFS4my/Q0) - Raku (Perl 6)

The part in the 27 byte version that is undercounted by Perl is `((||){2}||)`, the expression that multiplies possibilities by 11.

Perl forces *any* loop to exit after making a zero-width match (whereas PCRE only does so on loops whose quantifier has no maximum, which I think is more logical), so `(||){2}` needs to be changed to `(||)(||)`, adding 1 byte.

Perl prunes a group's alternatives down to one if they are all identical, but doesn't do this if even one alternative differs from the others. So `(||)` needs to be changed to `(()||)` in both places, adding 4 bytes.

After all that, it becomes `((()||)(()||)||)`. But that's longer than `(()||||||||||)`, so we use the latter instead, at just 3 bytes longer than `((||){2}||)`.

## Regex  `m` (<sub><sup>PCRE</sup></sub>), <s>73</s> 69 bytes

Without decomposing a fourth power into pentatope numbers, I'm pretty sure this is the best solution possible (it might golf down a tiny bit more than this, but not much):

```
^(?=(x*)\1{3}(xx())?(x())?)((?=\1(x*))(x+(|||)|\3(|)|\5).*(?=\7$)){4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVXrUuJIFP7PU7SZLe0OrUPA2xKj5SpVUqU4xWDt7KibiqGBlKGTymXEC3/3AfYR90HWPX1JCMLUUhA655z@zrW/9uN4e@z775@GbBRwhr6c9TtN9@z6vOPe9LoD9/fu@eACHdY@BdwP8yFDR7GfsObO5LjmT7wEufHtPXJQ3/jt6enxoZX/8fz8bTDZf5rg9z/xiYNnJrmzXltzPJthQk6wfBIMqjtLKAme1fHb2xt5u2th8dwjO6bQHvxCyOvu/J18BDYoMmPHjeuWXYkqzZKAj0VYC1kQgZR50@MVu@NawDMUwzJzWZJECfYjnmZIpmROWZp6Y0bQa5oN220fLNDREdJisZRyxoehjRKW5QlHlj1fwRTvfjRkFD1EUYgiZ@SFqYCVbjTcbXNv/96uIfgEI4Rldd0x0xiutsIKB6v23JxdnPYPTaKVFKXBC4tGuAz8cyGp2BNCpBfxwRE6UUn4UZ6hNioTJSI9Q25DMoI2Mj4kLzcbBuwy7rhBynqMwjydqEzKotTmtZynwZizIQojPlYPj6dPLLFlwabPru@FIYShc9dv7kMY@Y/I9Cn6EQVDZA69zIPaiSKJJXIchIXGJJsLDKKx6/WyMw3dmakXcAwAMsD4FgYhZBzHZNu6dxq2SkFNB4p9x8AnbcOGVd2J1Z9B8MkZ/DYIyHNAbDXdDJoKewX8GBYSugoU8DjPxHaZGLQQmQkr3qde5k9cmYu5WCu0hKV5mFHVAlufyq/d7x0pGY1SBkrIF1IYZ5MlAzP6wfwMdulOwOks/E/jIGRYD8XXL4M@if0d34VgMaEa43unf@0OOv2rbu900DkvxJ1vg07vvHOO3rTg6uZy0L3s9joUbcoo9b@OrUEWM72RwEjqblTPh3xqu0oxnJX6uPDuZcwdJdHUjb0sYwnHCcx97@byUgNU98Bhztgsg7IWK2edXsPiFRTIoBzKAoJWJpWum7yPAMpVGEyDKsi2ReyK0ZDF2f8aJczPkzSI@FpD6XYUJUjyzUs5y8AhITA6Vkc74FRNI7GLM1C054UgkAtOwlt3fAtcvziWLVVyx47gEkwcp0GQ8BzwnNkLBHAKUyjcKvZMF7oyqjhKwWDJc7GXsycX9lPEoUleFgXaqR5LVBebib28TxAlSD/AladPkprgMWrYqxbgB4tQTQLth975OIWG6jhAKZ51ZMGPC/cWWYNxC0b1urj5RMmWDeaIAc2vi23heaocV7yu9TVfepuyKYwDTsFQVmxrtgVlg37JcASGQhNhFVNQlIIvA0P1wEhVGu79Id6igCWkMoiiwoJkK3zWbnNZ9gco3KOtzB3B8qvxLvcB/fPX3whoU5GzDK@0VFS3fELl4a7yFHRIptyQ3wUzwFofhkrlRPAK9aiBNje1hw1HM1m/f913e9dXp4OzC7JclQo5FQycJTmrYIvW1n46cDq/NTfi/GckBaTGGF5ksUp@yqB8J9X7RCmBX8vrTsUNF@97k7Zq1i7drzVoc69WO6i1qCWXFgUV3aV7dJ8e0EP6q5BbFrWa//qj0Bun79uhdLF9@B8) - PCRE2 v10.33 / [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVbLUuNGFF3HX9FoUtAtN8SygWEsBMWAq3AVjymPqUwGiErIbVuF3FLpMZiHt_mAbLPJJsv5ILLMl-T2Q7KMnYrLklu37z332Uf-47sfh3kqLnfk-9-vjc0w9hPW3Nwzbl977wZsGHCGPh33Ok33-PKk415ddPvuz92T_inaq70LuB_mA4b2pdHW-KDmj70EufH1LXJQz_j48HB_18p_eXz80h_vPozxX3k23Nx77fyKDx08NcmN9dya4ekUE3KI5Z1g2LqxxCbB0zp-eXkhLzctLO47ZMsUu-9_JOR5e6bA_v7hA3nrx6DIjB03rlt2Jcg0SwI-ElHOZUEEUuZNDpb0DmoBz1AMy8xlSRIl2I94miGZoTlhaeqNGEHPaTZot33QQPv7SIvFUsoZH4Q2SliWJxxZ9mwJUzz70YBRdBdFIYqcoRemAla60XDXzZ3dW7uG4BMMEZbFdkdMY7haCyscrLp1dXx61Nszid6kKA2eWDTEZeA_FZKKPiFEehEfHKFDlYQf5RlqozJRItIzpBmSEbSR8SZ5aWwYYGXccIOU9RjCpI1VJmVRarNaztNgxNkAhREfqZvH0weW2LJgk0fX98IQwtC56yf3Loz8e2T6FH2LggEyB17mQe1EkcQSOQ7CYsck63MMorHr9bIzDd2ZiRdwDAAywPgaBiFkHMdk07p1GrZKQU0Hin3HwIdtw4ZV3YnVj0Hw4TFcawTkOSC2mm4GTQVbAT-ChYSuAgU8zjNhLhODFiIzYcXzxMv8sStzMedrhZawNA8zqlpg60P6ufu1IyXDYcpgE_KFFEbZeEHBjL4xPwMr3Qk4rIX_SRyEDOuh-Pyp3yOxv-W7ECwmVGN87fQu3X6nd969OOp3Tgpx50u_c3HSOUEvWnB-ddbvnnUvOhStyyj1r46tQeYzvZbASOpuVM-HvGu9SjGcpfq48OxlzB0m0cSNvSxjCccJzP3F1dmZBqjawGHO2DSDshYrZ9W-hsVLKJBBOZQFBK1MKl01eW8BlKswmARVkE2L2BWlAYuz_1VKmJ8naRDxlYrS7TBKkOSbp3KWgUNCIHisjnbAqZpGYhdnoGjPE0EgF5yEN274Brh-cixbbkmLLcElmDhOgyDhOeA5s-cI4BSmULhV7JnO98qo4igFhQXPhS1nDy7YU8ShSV4WBdqpHktUF8bEXrQTRAnSN3Dl6ZOkJniMGvayBvjBIlSTQPuhdz5OoaE6DtgU9zqy4OLCvUVWYFyDUr0uXoSiZIsKM8SA5lfFNvc8UY4rXlf6mi08TdgExgGnoCgrtjHdgLJBv2Q4AkOhibCKKShKwReBoXqgpCoNfwMGeIMClpDKIIoKC5Kt8Fm7zWXZ76Bw97ZSdwTLL8e72Af0z2-_I6BNRc4yvFJTUd3iCZWHu8pT0CGZckN-58wAa30YKpUTwSvU_QZaX9ce1hzNZL3eZc-9uDw_6h-fksWqVMipYOAsyVkFW7R2wWYhUZ3fijfi7L9ICkiNMTzPYpn8lEL5TKrvE7UJ_Fq-7lTc8OJV_6D-fG01aatmbdPdWoM2d2q197UWteTSorBFt-kO3aXv6R79IOSWRa2msv0X) - PCRE2 v10.40+

```
^                    # tail = N = input number
(?=
    (x*)\1{3}        # \1 = floor(tail / 4)
    (()xx)?(()x)?    # \3,\5 = {tail % 4} in binary:
                     # \3 set|unset = 2's place digit 1|0
                     # \5 set|unset = 1's place digit 1|0
)
(
    # Manipulate the number of possible matches to be exactly \1 * 4 + \2 == N
    (?=\1(x*))       # \7 = tail - \1
    (
        x+(|||)      # Add \1 * 4 to the number of possibilities of this iteration
    |
        \3(|)|\5     # Add \3*2 + \5 (where set=1 and unset=0) to the number of
                     # possibilities of this iteration
    )
    .*(?=\7$)        # tail = \7, i.e. the next multiple of \1 down from what it
                     # was when \7 was captured above.
){4}                 # Iterate the above 4 times, such that after finishing, each
                     # iteration could have been at any one of the N states.
```

This method does eventually win out against simplex decomposition:

1: <sup>`x`</sup>
   <sup>`x`</sup>

2: <sup>`x?x+`</sup>
   <sup>`^(?=(x*)\1(x()|))\2(x+(|)|\3).*(?=\1$)(?4)`</sup>

3: <sup>`(|xx|(|||)x)x*x+`</sup>
   <sup>`^(?=(x*)\1\1(x())?(x())?)((?=\1(x*))(x+(||)|\3|\5).*(?=\7$)){3}`</sup>

4: <sup>`(|xxx|((||){2}||)xx?)x*x*x+`</sup>
   <sup>`^(?=(x*)\1{3}(xx())?(x())?)((?=\1(x*))(x+(|||)|\3(|)|\5).*(?=\7$)){4}`</sup>

5: <sup>`x(|x{4}|x((||||){2}|)(|xx)|((|){6}||)xx)(x*){4}`</sup>
   <sup>`^(?=(x*)\1{4}(xx())?(x())?(x())?)((?=\1(x*))(x+(||||)|\3(|)|\5|\7).*(?=\9$)){5}`</sup>

6: <sup>`x(|x{5}|x((|){3,5}|)(|xxx)|(|)((||||){2,3}|)xxx?)(x*){5}`</sup>
   <sup>`^(?=(x*)\1{5}(xx())?(xx())?(x())?)((?=\1(x*))(x+(|||||)|\3(|)|\5(|)|\7).*(?=\9$)){6}`</sup>

7: <sup>`x(|x{6}|x(|){3,6}(|x{4})|xx(||)((||||||){2,3}|||||)(|xx)|xxx(|){4}((||||){2,3}|))(x*){6}`</sup>
   <sup>`^(?=(x*)\1{6}(xxx())?(xx())?(x())?)((?=\1(x*))(x+(||||||)|\3(||)|\5(|)|\7).*(?=\9$)){7}`</sup>

8: <sup>`x(|x{7}|x((||){5}||||)(|x{5})|xx(||){4}((|){4,5}|||||)(|xxx)|xxx((|){8}((|){2,5}|)|||)x?)(x*){7}`</sup>
   <sup>`^(?=(x*)\1{7}(x{4}())?(xx())?(x())?)((?=\1(x*))(x+(|){3}|\3(|||)|\5(|)|\7).*(?=\9$)){8}`</sup>

Answer (score 6):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) assembly, 30 DECLEs = 38 bytes

Let's try this on a processor lacking a multiply instruction. This code is intended to be run on an [Intellivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellivision).

CP-1610 instructions are encoded with 10-bit values, known as *'DECLE'* s. This subroutine is 30 DECLEs long, starting at $4808 and ending at $4825.

[Takes input in registers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7425/58563) *R0* and *R3*. Saves the result in *R2*.

```
                              ROMW  10            ; use 10-bit ROM
                              ORG   $4800         ; map program at address $4800

4800  02B8 000E               MVII  #14,    R0    ; example call
4802  02BB 0006               MVII  #6,     R3
4804  0004 0148 0008          CALL  addX4Y4
4807  0017                    DECR  PC            ; loop forever

4808  0275            addX4Y4 PSHR  R5            ; push the return address
4809  0004 0148 001A          CALL  square        ; compute R2 = R0^2
480C  0004 0148 0019          CALL  square2       ; compute R2 = R2^2
480F  0272                    PSHR  R2            ; push this result on the stack
4810  0098                    MOVR  R3,     R0    ; compute R2 = R3^2
4811  0004 0148 001A          CALL  square
4814  0004 0148 0019          CALL  square2       ; compute R2 = R2^2
4817  02F2                    ADD@  R6,     R2    ; add this result to the intermediate one
4818  02B7                    PULR  PC            ; return

4819  0090            square2 MOVR  R2,     R0    ; copy R2 to R0
481A  0081            square  MOVR  R0,     R1    ; copy R0 to R1
481B  01D2                    CLRR  R2            ; initialize R2 = result
481C  0200 0002               B     halve         ; start by halving R1
481E  00C2            add     ADDR  R0,     R2    ; add R0 to R2
481F  0048            loop    SLL   R0            ; double R0
4820  0079            halve   SARC  R1            ; halve R1
4821  0221 0004               BC    add           ; was the LSB set?
4823  022C 0005               BNEQ  loop          ; is R1 now equal to zero?
4825  00AF                    JR    R5            ; return
```

#### Example run

Running the above code (with *R0* = 14 and *R3* = 6) gives:

```
> b 4807
Set breakpoint at $4807
> r
Hit breakpoint at $4807
 0900 0000 9B20 0006 01FE 4817 02F1 4807 S-----iq  DECR R7
           ^^^^
```

*R2* is set to $9B20, which is 39712 in decimal.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 12 bytes

Includes `+1` for `p`

Works for 1 or more numbers each given on a separate line on STDIN

```
(echo 2; echo 3) | perl -pe '$\+=$_**4}{'
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 11 bytes

```hs
sum.map(^4)
```

This is a function that takes the parameters as a list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P822uDRXLzexQCPORPN/bmJmnoKtQko@F2dBUWZeiYKKQppCtJGOgnEsioihiY6CGaqQgY6CkWnsfwA)

Comment: Same bytecount: `a#b=a^4+b^4`

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

Takes input as an array of integers; can handle negatives and more than 2 integers at a time. Add `N` at the beginning to take input as individual integers.

```
xp4
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=eHA0&input=WzE0LDZd)

---

### Explanation

`p4` raises each element to the power of 4 and `x` reduces by addition.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 11 bytes

```
:*:*$:*:*+n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/30rLSksFRGjn/f//X7fMCIiNAQ)

Takes values through the `-v` flag. Dupe and multipy, dupe and multiply, and repeat with the other value before adding the two together and printing.

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 9 bytes

```
.+
****
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bSwsIuOL//zc04TIDAA)

Input should be linefeed-separated.

#### Explanation

```
.+
****
```

`*` is Retina's repetition operator. It has implicit operands `$&` and `_`, respectively, so the substitution pattern is short for `$&*$&*$&*$&*_`. It's also right-associative, if the regex matches a decimal number **n**, this generates a string of **n<sup>4</sup>** underscores (i.e. a unary representation of the fourth power of **n**).

```
_
```

To sum the two results and convert the sum back to decimal, we simply count the number of underscores in the string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
⁴Ʃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UeOWYyv//4820TGJBQA)

Takes input as a list.

Comment: Knew there would be a language with a built-in for **4, congrats.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Takes a list as argument. The list may have any length and contain any numbers, even complex ones.

```apl
+.*∘4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRtPa1HHTNMgBwFIx0FYy6uNAVDEx0FMxDDQEfByBQA)

`+.*` is a variant on matrix product, `+.×` as follows: `a b+.×c d` is `(a×c)+(b×d)` and `a b+.×c` is `(a×c)+(b×c)`. So `a b+.*c` is `(a*c)+(b*c)`. `*` is power.

`∘4` curry four as right argument. This results in a monadic function `(a*4)+(b*4)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>7</strike> 6 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Adám

```
1#.^&4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX14tRM/mtyKXClJmfkK6QpGCkYw5iGJgpmcHEDBSNTBDveUCHeSCHeWCHeRMHI@D8A)

Works for lists with arbitrary length

`^&4` - each item of the list to the 4-th power

`1#.` - sum of all 4-th powers by base-1 conversion

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tfUdrOJMrP5rcilwpSZn5CukKRgpGMOYhiYKZnBxAwUjUwQ73lAh3kgh3lgh3kTByPg/AA)

### Alternative

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
+/ .^4:
```

This is a variant of the matrix product, analogue of Adám's APL solution

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tfUV9OJMrP5rcilwpSZn5CukKRgpGMOYhiYKZnBxAwUjUwQ73lAh3kgh3lgh3kTByPg/AA)

Comment: 6 bytes: [`1#.^&4`](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX14tRM/mtyKXClJmfkK6QpGCkYw5iGJgpmcHEDBSNTBDveUCHeSCHeWCHeRMHI@D8A "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám Thanks, I forgot to try to add up the numbers by base-1 conversion.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 20 bytes

```
lambda x,y:x**4+y**4
```

Comment: You can remove the assignment to `f` as this isn't a recursive function.

Comment: @Shaggy Maybe I'm confused but how else would my answer take any input? Wouldn't I then be defining something that is essentially 'lost' right after being interpreted? It's not like I can feed input in via args, for example. Or it is normal in codegolf that those bytes 'f=' are not counted?

Comment: What I meant was: you don't need to include it in your byte count. Anonymous functions/lambdas are valid.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
K^s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zuu@P//aEMTHbNYAA)

This can handle more than two input values, as well as negative inputs.

#### Explanation:

Fasten your seat belts, this might blow your mind!

```
       % Implicit input
K      % Push literal 4
 ^     % Raise each element of the input vector to the 4th power
  s    % Sum
```

Also works:

```
4^s    % Push 4 and raise input to it, then sum
UUs    % Square input twice, then sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 15 bytes

Does exactly what it says on the tin.

```js
a=>b=>a**4+b**4
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>b=>a**4+b**4

console.log(f(2)(3))
console.log(f(14)(6))
console.log(f(0)(25))
```

Comment: [Ah, nuts!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/156107/58974)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
4mO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJNf///9oQxMdXbNYAA)

**Explanation**

```
4m    # raise each to the power of 4
  O   # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, C++ => 29 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Jonathan Frech

```cpp
#define Q(a,b)a*a*a*a+b*b*b*b
```

Test cases :

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Q(%d,%d) = %d\n", 2, 3, Q(2, 3));
    printf("Q(%d,%d) = %d\n", 14, 6, Q(14, 6));
    printf("Q(%d,%d) = %d\n", 0, 25, Q(0, 25));
}
```

Comment: Could you not drop the space in `) a`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 11 bytes

```julia
a$b=a^4+b^4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/USXJNjHORDspzuR/QVFmXklOnoahiYqZJheMZ6BiZKr5HwA)

---

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes

```julia
!a=sum(a.^4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fMdG2uDRXI1EvzkTzf0FRZl5JTp6GYrShiYJZrCYXQsBAwcg0VvM/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 10 bytes

```
=A1^4+B1^4
```

Nothing to see here.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 26 bytes

```c
f(a,b){a=a*a*a*a+b*b*b*b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1EnSbM60TZRCwy1k7TA0Lr2f25iZp6GZnVBUWZeSZqGkmpKDRgp6aRpGOkYawIpQxMdMxBtoGNkqqkJ1AIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
*4S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/LJPj///9GOgrGAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 0 + 24 bytes

Compile this code

```c
main(){
    printf("%d\n",x(2,3));
    printf("%d\n",x(14,6));
    printf("%d\n",x(0,25));
}
```

With this flag:

```c
-D=x(a,b)a*a*a*a+b*b*b*b
```

[Try it online! (GCC Tio)](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@//9/bmJmnoZmNRdnQVFmXkmahpJqSkyekk6FhpGOsaamNaa4oYmOGVYJAx0jU5BE7f9/yWk5ienF/3VdbCs0EnWSNBO1wFA7SQsMAQ)
[Try it online! (Bash Compile example)](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifmpyRr6CknJmXnFOakqpgU1ySkpmvl2GnpGBnp5Col8wFUZCbmJmnoVmNJqqgUFCUmVeSphGjpJoSkxejpFOhYaRjrKlpTYRCQxMdM@JUGugYmWKqrIXzudKTk0EMBaWY/7outhUaiTpJmolaYKidpAWGMf@VuPT0E/XyS0v@AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 31 bytes

```
...)...
..IEM..
.)4s^}.
u......
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09PTxOIufT0PF19QbSmSXFcrR5XqR4Y/P8fbaRjHAsA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 16 bytes

```r
pryr::f(x^4+y^4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P81Gt6CossjKKk2jIs5EuzLORPN/moaRjoKxJleahqGJjoIZiGGgo2BkqvkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 16 bytes

```
->a,b{a**4+b**4}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y5RJ6k6UUvLRDsJSNRycRUopEUb6RjHghkGOkamsf//AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 21 bytes

```java
a->b->a*a*a*a+b*b*b*b
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jc5NC4JAEAbgu79ijmq5lH1cLI9Bh04eo8O4mqyt66KjIOJvt8X0nLwwvDAPzOTYolfqVOXJZ@QS6xoeKFRvAdSEJDjkRrCGhGTvRnESpWK3uVzuitIsrbbr0FzCEDhcYUQvjL0Q3Smb2J0yBuYygBm6iaU5P3/RliKBwnxmR1QJlT1f6PQTjbqa0oKVDTFtNiSVzRlqLTvbd@ZycJzgH94fF31eoXcL9k8/PVjD@AU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 9 bytes

```
*⁴+*⁴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtf61HjFm0Q8d9aoTixUkFJJV7B1k6hOk2hRiW@VkkhLb9IwcZIwdhOR8HG0ETBDEQbKBiZ2ln/BwA)

Comment: @EsolangingFruit The problem is that along with `*` WhateverCode lambdas there are also `**` HyperWhatever lambdas; so it would have to be written as `* **4+* **4`, or else it would would be seen as `** *4+** *4` which doesn't work. (`(**⁴)(2,3)` results in `(16,18)`)

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills I guess that makes sense. Why am I surprised Perl supports Unicode superscript exponents?

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5

```
sm^d4
```

[Online test](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%5Ed4&input=%5B2%2C3%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B2%2C%203%5D%0A%5B16%2C%206%5D%0A%5B0%2C%2025%5D&debug=0).

```
  ^d4     # lambda to take 4th power
     Q    # implicit input
 m        # map lambda over input
s         # sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 8 bytes

```
Sum@`^&4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxC8IwEEb3@xU3FNFyg9bqXNBZBN2OE2O8xAyGYs7fHwvSb3pveJ8zc/6l9aghZeUmUL1838P9tuirwLLFh8aU0bRYyhHbFZxUn4WbcfRRYM7MEwNO445wK/TnTU@4n2VN2O0EROD8Sdmu0@PBFS0cCM1L/QE)

Takes input as a pair of integers.

### Explanation

This is a composition of two functions:

- `Sum`
- `` `^&4 ``

The first executed is `` `^&4 ``, which is equivalent to:

```
`^&4
RBond[`^, 4]
RBond[{_1 ^ _2}, 4]
{_1 ^ 4}
```

That is, a function that raises its argument to the fourth power. This vectorizes over the input array. Then, `Sum` takes the sum of these elements.

### Alternative approaches

```
Sum@`^&4@V    ?? 11 bytes, input is two arguments
{Sum[_^4]}    ?? 11 bytes, input is array
{_^4+_2^4}    ?? 11 bytes, input is two arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Pyramid-Scheme), 220 bytes

```
           ^
          / \
         /   \
        /  +  \
       /       \
      ^---------^
     /^\       /^\
    ^---^     ^---^
   /#\ /4\   /#\ /4\
  ^--- ---  ^--- ---
 /l\       /l\
/ine\     /ine\
-----     -----
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3dCoAwCEbvfQqhywihehwRogYNVkRd9fRWrv0IsnPchx73OW1@6a55dZtTxVIChQkZKsFKX2srp/9NA@lS/ftIOEUlhr6I5LDFqGGkkQtB/MSvMwFSyMsCA/ndRTcCO2tupNrD8AA)

`line` pyramids obtain a line from STDIN, `#` pyramids cast their arguments into numbers, `^` pyramids perform exponentiation, and the `+` pyramid adds two things together.

Answer (score 1):

## Minkolang 0.15, 10 bytes

```
$n4;r4;+N.
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=%24n4%3Br4%3B%2BN%2E&input=2%203)

### Explanation

```
$n4;r4;+N.
$n           take all input as numbers     [a, b]
  4;         raise to the fourth           [a, b^4]
    r        reverse stack                 [b^4, a]
     4;      raise to the fourth           [b^4, a^4]
       +     add                           [b^4 + a^4]
        N    output                        []
         .   terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 25 bytes

```
(int x,int y)=>x^^4+y^^4;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S/mfWFqSr5Bm@18jM69EoUIHRFZq2tpVxMWZaFcCCev/mbkF@UUlCsUlKXpAnJlvzVWWn5mikJuYmaehWc1VXpRZkpqTp5GmYaRjrKlpzVX7HwA)

A simple lambda that performs exponentiation on each of its arguments, with `^^` being the exponentiation operator.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:a**4+b**4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8kqUUvLRDsJSPwvKMrMK9FI0zDSMdbU5ILxDE10zJC4BjpGppqa/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## IBM/Lotus Notes Formula, 17 bytes

```
@Sum(@Power(a;4))
```

Field formula that takes its input from a multi-value numeric field on the same form. Works because for most Formula functions, if a list is given as input then the formula will apply the given function recursively to every item in the list.

There is no TIO for Notes but here's a screenshot of one of the test cases:

[image: Test Case]

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 8 bytes

```
L,4^$4^+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HxyROxSRO@79KTmJuUkqigqGdkZ0xl/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```python
lambda i:sum(x**4for x in i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHTqrg0V6NCS8skLb9IoUIhM08hU/N/QVFmXolCmka0oYmOWazmfwA)

Alternative approach for Python (albeit slightly longer than the more obvious one). Takes input as a list of integers.

-2 with thanks to @JonathanAllan

Comment: You can drop the `[` and `]`

Comment: @JonathanAllan - I was sure I'd tried that and got a syntax error but it seems to work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Perl 6, 15 bytes

```
{$^a**4+$^b**4}
```

An anonymous lambda.
[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X5xYqZCTmZdarFeUmlKanKrxv1olLlFLy0RbJS4JSNX@1/xvxGUMAA)

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 5 bytes

Prompts for screen input of a two element vector. Seems to work for negative inputs

```
+/⎕*4
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
ṁ^4
```

Input as a list, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxjiT////Rxua6JjFAgA)

#### Alternative, 4 bytes

One byte more but I like this more:

```
¤+^4
```

Expects two arguments, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9AS7TiT////G5r8NwMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), 8 bytes

```
4*↔4*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PzU0sSfz/30TrUdsUEy3t////G/03BgA)

It's trivial enough for ,,,. :P

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
{4f#:+}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/2iRN2Uq79n/d/2hDAwMFI@NYAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Momema](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/momema), 68 bytes

```
2*-8k03*2 2 01*3j02+*2*3 1+-1*1j=*1k*001k3 4*2 2*-8 02k2 03k1-8+*2*4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fco7CoAwDADQ3VNkTgnkU6SLhxF0sKFW0PMb65tf621va4QiFWdDBQUWtMqaUNFAEglKXVAcmcUN8p9GB1Yf2Vyo/DdHSJ7mt1/P0c87aPsA)

Doesn't work for zeroes. Awaiting clarification from OP.

### Explanation

```
2   *-8    #  o = read num
k   0      #  procedure square(o, LABEL):
3   *2     #    original = o
2   0      #    o = 0
1   *3     #    i = original
j   0      #    do {
2   +*2*3  #      o = o + original
1   +-1*1  #      i = i - 1
j   =*1    #    while (i != 0)
k   *0     #    goto LABEL
           #  LABEL = sq0
           #  square(o, LABEL); sq0:
0   1      #  LABEL = sq1
k   3      #  square(o, LABEL); sq1:
4   *2     #  t = o
2   *-8    #  o = read num
0   2      #  LABEL = sq2
k   2      #  square(o, LABEL); sq2:
0   3      #  LABEL = sq3
k   1      #  square(o, LABEL); sq3:
-8  +*2*4  #  print num t + o
```

This program defines a "procedure" which squares memory cell 2 (using 1 and 3 as temporary cells) and then jumps based on the value of cell 0.

Comment: Zero is in the test cases (and was so even in the base revision), so it does have to work, no clarification from OP needed. Why not just modify this solution to handle zero properly?

Answer (score 0):

## [Physica](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Physica), 13 bytes

```
=>a;b:a^4+b^4
```

### Demo

Note that physica is not on TIO yet. This is a lambda function, which can be called using `F[a; b]`, as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 10 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/xexp[;4]
```

**Example:**

```
q)k)+/xexp[;4]2 3
97f
q)k)+/xexp[;4]0 25
390625f
```

**Explanation:**

Pretty trivial...

```
+/xexp[;4] / the solution
  xexp[;4] / xexp does x^y, with y = 4 
+/         / sum over
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
４＾╶４＾＋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjE0JXVGRjNFJXUyNTc2JXVGRjE0JXVGRjNFJXVGRjBC,i=MTQlMEE2)

Answer (score 0):

## [Phoenix](https://github.com/senselogic/PHOENIX), 28 bytes

```php
echo$argv[1]**4+$argv[2]**4;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8jIT83LrPj/PzU5I18lsSi9LNowVkvLRBvCNgKxrf///2/03xgA)

Phoenix is a variant of PHP designed to be lightweight in terms of syntax. TO this end, it does a pretty okay job. A function would be longer, so this seems to be the shortest way. (The documentation is sparse, and I don't know much PHP myself.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
,*4S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19HyyT4////hib/zQA)

**Explanation**

```
,       pair
 *4     to the power of four
   S    sum
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 49 bytes

```
ij➡️➕i 4j 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f9hfn/jh/m97VwKCkBqWVppXvJ/ED/zw/xZDVkg4tG8he939INYQPG@R/OmArU0ZSqYgKgsENXb@R@keUYDkJiyEGTMWgWQOQqGJgpmCoYGXGAlAA)